# Where is C not a subset of C++?

Tags: c++, c

I read in a lot of books that C is a subset of C++.

Some books say that C is a subset of C++, *except for the little details*.

What are some cases when code will compile in C, but not C++?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you compare `C89` with `C++` then here are a couple of things

#### No tentative definitions in C++

```
int n;
int n; // ill-formed: n already defined
```

#### int[] and int[N] not compatible (no compatible types in C++)

```
int a[1];
int (*ap)[] = &a; // ill-formed: a does not have type int[]
```

#### No K&R function definition style

```
int b(a) int a; { } // ill-formed: grammar error
```

#### Nested struct has class-scope in C++

```
struct A { struct B { int a; } b; int c; };
struct B b; // ill-formed: b has incomplete type (*not* A::B)
```

#### No default int

```
auto a; // ill-formed: type-specifier missing
```

---

C99 adds a whole lot of other cases

#### No special handling of declaration specifiers in array dimensions of parameters

```
// ill-formed: invalid syntax
void f(int p[static 100]) { }
```

#### No variable length arrays

```
// ill-formed: n is not a constant expression
int n = 1;
int an[n];
```

#### No flexible array member

```
// ill-formed: fam has incomplete type
struct A { int a; int fam[]; };
```

#### No restrict qualifier for helping aliasing analysis

```
// ill-formed: two names for one parameter?
void copy(int *restrict src, int *restrict dst);
```

Comment: @mehrdad, thanks. oO didn't know one has to create a variable already when declaring a nested struct in C. Fixed.

Comment: There's another (useless) C89 to C++ one: `typedef;` is a legal TU in C, but not in C++.

Comment: Notice that `auto a;` is valid in the newest C++ standard revision.

Comment: @FUZxxl really? What will be the deduced type of `a`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That depends on how you use `a`. I think this syntax is only legal if you initialize the variable in the definition.

Comment: @FUZxxl ah thanks. So `auto x;` is not valid in the newest revision, but for example `auto x = 0;` is. I was a bit shocked at first :)

Comment: See http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm, or should I say C that.

Answer (score 56):

In C, `sizeof('a')` is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

In C++, `sizeof('a')` is equal to `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: That can be simpified to: In C, `'a'` is an `int`. In C++, `'a'` is a `char`.

Answer (score 48):

C++ has new keywords as well. The following is valid C code but won't compile under C++:

```
int class = 1;
int private = 2;
int public = 3;
int virtual = 4;
```

Comment: it's true, but that's exactly what subset means.

Comment: @yeyeyerman: No. For it to be a subset, all C code would have to be valid C++ as well. The code in this example is valid C but not C++.

Comment: No, if C was a strict subset of C++, then every C program would be a valid C++ program, but that's not true. The question is why it's not true, and this is one example of why.

Comment: Ha! Didn't think about this one!

Answer (score 25):

There are plenty of things. Just a simple example (it should be enough to prove C is not a proper subset of C++):

```
int* test = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

should compile in C but not in C++.

Comment: C++ should require an explicit cast to `int*`.

Comment: Long answer: malloc returns `void *`, which in C can be assigned to any pointer type, and C++ cannot be assigned to any other pointer type.

Comment: Imagist: a C compiler, as defined by ANSI C89 standard, shouldn't complain.

Comment: It's legal C.  The cast is unnecessary, possible to get wrong, and covers up a failure to include <stdlib.h>.  I consider Mehrdad's statement to be the right way to write it in C.

Comment: @Imagist: I usually hear the opposite from C programmers. They consider it poor style to add the cast, as it may conceal bugs. Good C code does *not* use the cast.

Comment: @jalf: I consider using implicit function declarations to be poor style, and I strongly encourage always compiling with -Wall -Werror (GCC).  This prevents the case where a cast here would mask a failure to include <stdlib.h>.  If there's any chance whatsoever the code might get compiled as C++, it's better to do the cast.

Comment: @Adam:  If there's any chance that the code might get compiled as C++, it's arguably better to remove the cast.  Most C++ compilers will compile C as well, and I'd rather know if a compiler is compiling C as if it were C++.

Comment: Prior to C89, malloc() and calloc() returned char*, so an explicit  cast was necessary if the target pointer was of a different type.  But if you're working with a compiler *that* old, you have bigger problems AFAIC.

Comment: @jalf: Hang out on comp.lang.c and you'll see religious debates about it on a fairly regular basis. Apparently, this is as big a deal as using EMACS over Vim.

Comment: There is a question all about there here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 20):

In C++, if you declare a `struct`, `union`, or `enum`, its name is immediately accessible without any qualifiers:

```
struct foo { ... };
foo x; // declare variable
```

In C, this won't work, because types thus declared live in their own distinct namespaces. Thus, you have to write:

```
struct foo { ... };
struct foo x; // declare variable
```

Notice the presence of `struct` there on the second line. You have to do the same for `union` and `enum` (using their respective keywords), or use the `typedef` trick:

```
typedef struct { ... } foo;
foo x; // declare variable
```

Consequently, you can have several types of different kinds named the same in C, since you can disambiguate:

```
struct foo { ... };
typedef enum { ... } foo;

struct foo x;
foo y;
```

In C++, however, while you can prefix a `struct` name with keyword `struct` whenever you reference it, the namespaces are merged, and so the above C snippet isn't valid. On the other hand, C++ specifically makes an exception to allow a type and a typedef for that type to have the same name (obviously with no effect), to allow the use of `typedef` trick unchanged from C.

Comment: Your last example is invalid C: The three tags (`struct`, `union` and `enum`) share the same namespace. A better example would be `struct foo { ... }; typedef enum { ... } foo;`

Comment: @schot: you're of course right, thank you for the correction. Updated.

Comment: `typedef struct foo *foo;` is another good example: if you have a C header file with this line, you cannot `#include` it in a C++ file and still compile as C++ code (e.g. clang++ reports "`error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct foo *' vs 'foo')`"). This can specifically cause problems linking C++ code with C code that does not follow C++'s implicit `typedef struct foo foo;` convention.

Answer (score 14):

This also depends on what variety of C you're using.  Stroustrup made C++ as compatible as he could, and no more compatible, with the 1989 ANSI and 1990 ISO standards, and the 1995 version changed nothing.  The C committee went in a somewhat different direction with the 1999 standard, and the C++ committee has changed the next C++ standard (probably out next year or so) to conform with some of the changes.

Stroustrup lists incompatibilities with C90/C95 in Appendix B.2 of "The C++ Programming Language", Special Edition (which is 3rd edition with some added material):

`'a'` is an `int` in C, a `char` in C++.

The sizeof an enum is `int` in C, not necessarily in C++.

C++ has `//` comments to end of line, C doesn't (although it's a common extension).

In C++, a `struct foo {` definition puts `foo` into the global namespace, while in C it would have to be referred to as `struct foo`.  This allows a `struct` definition to shadow a name in an outer scope, and has a few other consequences.  Also, C allows larger scope for `struct` definitions, and allows them in return type and argument type declarations.

C++ is fussier about types in general.  It won't allow an integer to be assigned to an `enum`, and `void *` objects cannot be assigned to other pointer types without a cast.  In C, it's possible to provide an overlarge initializer (`char name[5] = "David"` where C will discard the trailing null character).

C89 allowed implicit `int` in many contexts, and C++ doesn't.  This means that all functions must be declared in C++, while in C89 it was often possible to get by with assuming `int` for everything applicable in the function declaration.

In C, it's possible to jump from outside a block to inside using a labeled statement.  In C++, this isn't allowed if it skips an initialization.

C is more liberal in external linkage.  In C, a global `const` variable is implicitly `extern`, and that's not true in C++.  C allows a global data object to be declared several times without an `extern`, but that's not true in C++.

Many C++ keywords are not keywords in C, or are `#define`d in standard C headers.

There are also some older features of C that aren't considered good style any more.  In C, you can declare a function with the argument definitions after the list of arguments.  In C, a declaration like `int foo()` means that `foo()` can take any number of any type of arguments, while in C++ it's equivalent to `int foo(void)`.

That seems to cover everything from Stroustrup.

Comment: Let's not forget the fact that, in C, you must declare variables at the beginning of a scope (i.e., immediately after an opening brace), whereas, C++ allows variable declarations anywhere.

Comment: However, that's something C++ can do that C can't.  I think we're looking at things you can do in C but not C++.

Comment: @RobH: That's true for C89 but not for C99.

Answer (score 10):

If you use gcc, you can use the warning `-Wc++-compat` to give you warnings about C code which is dubious in C++ in some way. Its currently used in gcc itself, and its gotten a lot better recently (maybe try a nightly version to get the best you can).

(This doesn't strictly answer the question, but folk might like it).

Comment: I thought I would never upvote a non-answer answer

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int new (int n) {
    return n/2;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", new(10));
    return 0;
}
```

See also [the C++ FAQ entry](http://parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.11).

Comment: So you're saying that `new` is not a reserved keyword in C.

Answer (score 5):

The single biggest difference I think is that this is a valid C source file:

```
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Note that I haven't declared `foo` anywhere.

Aside from language differences, C++ also makes some changes to the library that it inherited from C, e.g. some functions return `const char *` instead of `char *`.

Comment: Right, prototypes are not required in C but it is usually considered bad practice to not use them.

Comment: You should do `s,C,C89,` and note that it is an invalid C99 source file.

Comment: Is it invalid or just deprecated in C99 though?

Comment: @jalf the C99 draft documents the changes to C89, and includes both "remove implicit int" and "remove implicit function declaration".

Answer (score 3):

A number of the answers here cover syntax differences that would cause C++ compilers to fail on C89 (or C99) source code.  However, there are some subtle language differences that are legal in both languages but that would produce different behavior.  The `sizeof (char)` difference that Naveen mentioned is one example, but [Write a program that will print "C" if compiled as an (ANSI) C program, and "C++" if compiled as a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c/) lists some others.

Answer (score -2):

C compilers generally allowed a little corner cutting that C++ doesn't. C++ is much more strict than C. And generally, some of these differences are compiler-dependant. g++ allows some things that the Intel C++ compiler doesn't, for instance. Even fairly well written C code won't compile with a modern C++ compiler.