# antlr : C++ target with visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, antlr

the Antlr site is not clear on the subject of compiling a grammar for C++, 
it says that the tool will generate C  code compatible with C++,  what dose it mean?   will I be able to compile this code with VS 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2008 has both C and C++ compiler (and C++ compiler can compile C code, this is what they meant), I don't think you'll have any problems.

They say: "C target as of release 3.1 is C++ compatible, compile .c files as C++. C+ classes will be provided as a separate library later in 2008."

Meaning it's C++ compatible.

Comment: It will generate C code that is compilable with a C++ compiler

Answer (score 1):

[C is mostly a subset of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples). But the generated C code should not go off the C++ beaten path, so will should be valid C++.

Visual Studio has a C/C++ compiler, as you are compiling the generated parser, you do not need to worry about the C/C++ distinction. Just compile the code as C++.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "C code compatible with C++" means that the code generation targets the common subset of C and C++. Hence, it does not use the token `class` which has different meanings in C and C++, etctera. But it can use `int` and `foo`, where C and C++ agree.

As a result, the code generated can be compiled by both C and C++ compilers. Visual Studio contains both (via `/TC` and `/TP` flags) so you could use either mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded a C++ Target for ANTLR. check out the ANTLR wiki under Runtime Libraries - C++ Target

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29130826