# Write a program that will print "C" if compiled as an (ANSI) C program, and "C++" if compiled as a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, compiler-specific

Taken from http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/riddles/cs.shtml

It looks very compiler specific to me. Don't know where to look for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
#ifdef __cplusplus
printf("C++\n");
#else
printf("C\n");
#endif
return 0;
}
```

Or is there a requirement to do this without the official standard?

Comment: Just made the output agree with the question.

Comment: That's correct. The C++ 1998 standard says: "The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value `199711L` when compiling a C++ translation unit".  (Section 16.8: `[cpp.predefined]`)

Comment: Of course, a really nasty C implementation could define __cplusplus.

Comment: Nit-pick - that isn't a program; it is just the operational core of a program. :D

Comment: `__cplusplus` is defined to be 199711L *only when* the compiler is completely conforming. gcc, for example, still defines `__cplusplus` to be 1.

Comment: @stakx, KennyTM: Be careful. That number will change in C++0x.

Comment: @Neil, in the C99 standard, section 6.10.8.5 explicitly forbid the implementation from defining __cplusplus. But nothing of the sort in C89.

Comment: @anon: I know at least one that does - MSVC in C (C89) mode (IIRC)

Answer (score 49):

### 1. Abuse C++ automatic `typedef`s

(Note that the `struct` needs to be declared in an inner scope so that it takes precedence over the outer name in C++.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x;

    {
        struct x { char dummy[2]; };
        printf("%s\n", sizeof (x) == 1 ? "C" : "C++");
    }
}
```

A similar version that doesn't rely on the ambiguity between `sizeof (type)` and `sizeof (variable)`, using only types:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef char t;

    {
        struct t { char dummy[2]; };
        printf("%s\n", sizeof (t) == 1 ? "C" : "C++");
    }
}
```

### 2. Abuse C++ `struct`/`class` equivalence, automatic `typedef`s, and automatically-generated default constructors

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int isC = 0;
void Foo() { isC = 1; }

int main(void)
{
    struct Foo { int dummy; };
    Foo();
    printf("%s\n", isC ? "C" : "C++");
}
```

### 3. Abuse nested `struct` declarations in C

Also see [Symbol clashing of inner and outer structs, C++ vs C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628679/symbol-clashing-of-inner-and-outer-structs-c-vs-c)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct inner { int dummy; } t;

    {
        struct outer { struct inner { t dummy[2]; } dummy; };
        printf("%s\n",
               sizeof (struct inner) == sizeof (t)
               ? "C++"
               : "C");
    }
}
```

### 4. Abuse `//` comments

This won't work with C99 or with C89 compilers that support `//` as an extension.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",
           0 //* */
           +1
           ? "C++"
           : "C");
}
```

or alternatively:

```c
    printf("%s\n",
           1 //* */ 2
           ? "C++"
           : "C");
```

### 5. `sizeof` differences with `char` literals

Note that this isn't guaranteed to be portable since it's possible that some hypothetical platform could use bytes with more than 8 bits, in which case `sizeof(char)` could be the same as `sizeof(int)`. (Also see [Can sizeof(int) ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation))

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", sizeof 'a' == 1 ? "C++" : "C");
}
```

### 6. Abuse differences in when lvalue⇒rvalue conversions are performed

This is based off of the 5.16, 5.17, 5.18 example in the ISO C++03 standard, and it works in gcc but not in MSVC (possibly due to a compiler bug?).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    void* array[2];
    printf("%s\n",
           (sizeof (((void) 0), array) / sizeof (void*) == 1)
           ? "C"
           : "C++");
}
```

### 7. Abuse differences in the way C and C++'s grammars parse the ternary operator

This one isn't strictly legal, but some compilers are lax.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int isCPP = 1;
    printf("%s\n", (1 ? isCPP : isCPP = 0) ? "C++" : "C");
}
```

(You also could check for the `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro (or various other macros), but I think that doesn't follow the spirit of the question.)

I have implementations for all of these at:
http://www.taenarum.com/csua/fun-with-c/c-or-cpp.c

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard requires a char to be 1 byte, and a byte to be 8 bits.

Comment: No, `char` by definition is 1 byte, and a byte must be *at least* 8 bits, but it can be more.  That's why `CHAR_BIT` exists.

Comment: It requires char to be 1 byte. The number of bits in a byte is implementation-defined.

Comment: +1. Gotta love an answer where one option is non-portable and the other six are described as abuse :-)

Comment: Could someone explain why the solution 1 works the way it does in C? I didn’t think that struct x { ... } was a legal Syntax in C. What does it do?

Comment: @jacques `struct x { ... }` is the typical way to declare a `struct` in C with type `struct x`.  If you wanted a `typedef` so you don't need to type `struct` all the time when using it, you'd do `typedef struct x { ... } simpler_name`.  Note that the `struct` *tag* (`x`) and the `typedef` (`simpler_name`) live in separate C namespaces, so you also can do `typedef struct x { ... } x`.  C++ creates such `typedef`s implicitly for `struct` and `class`, hence `x` in approach #1 resolves differently in C++ than in C.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin ! It's been so many years since I did something with C, so I guess I got confused... Just remembered that I always used typedef struct ..., but not why. So, in C++, I can access the struct as 'x', whereas in C it's 'struct x', so sizeof(x) is the size of the char x...

Answer (score 44):

We had to do a similar assignment at school. We were not allowed to use preprocessor (except for `#include` of course). The following code uses the fact that in C, type names and structure names form separate namespaces whereas in C++ they don't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int X;
int main()
{
    struct X { int ch[2]; };
    if (sizeof(X) != sizeof(struct X))
        printf("C\n");
    else
        printf("C++\n");
}
```

Comment: It is not true that in C++ they don't form separate namespaces, they are kept separate by the compiler, **but** the compiler will lookup symbols in *both* namespaces (first in the non-user defined types, then on the user defined types). There are a few ways of testing it, the simplest of which is `typedef struct X {} Y; void X();` compiles, but if you add `void Y();` you will get a compiler error: the symbol `Y`, in the non-user-defined namespaces is already used by the `typedef`.

Answer (score 16):

```
puts(sizeof('a') == sizeof(int) ? "C" : "C++");
```

Comment: This is actually not guaranteed to work. `sizeof(int)` can be 1 if `CHAR_BIT` is at least 16.

Comment: Oak, in C, character literals are of type `int`, in C++ they're of type `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("This is %s\n", sizeof 'a' == sizeof(char) ? "C++" : "C");
    return 0;
}
```

And [here](http://grprakash.googlepages.com/confusion) is some nice reading on C and C++ differences.

Answer (score 2):

Just look to see if the `__STDC__` and `__cplusplus` compiler macros are defined.

Answer (score 1):

One word, `__cplusplus`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the intent is to write something that depends on differences between the languages themselves, not just predefined macros. Though it's technically not absolutely guaranteed to work, something like this is probably closer to what's desired:

```
int main() { 
    char *names[] = { "C", "C++"};

    printf("%s\n", names[sizeof(char)==sizeof('C')]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same rant as for Matthew Slattery, this may not work on all platforms.

Comment: @avakar:Theoretically sort of true -- that's why I said It's not absolutely guaranteed to work. At the same time, the basic design of the C I/O library depends on EOF being different from any value of unsigned char. That implies that sizeof(int)>sizeof(unsigned char). Even though there was an idea that sizeof(char)==sizeof(int) should be allowed, it's really impossible to make C work that way, so the code above really does work dependably.

Comment: Don't confuse the result of `sizeof` with the type's allowed range of values.

Comment: Jerry, I don't think you're correct. `EOF` is required to be negative, so it's true that it must be different from any value of `unsigned char`. However I don't see how it implies `sizeof(int)>sizeof(unsigned char)`. `int` is not required to hold all values of `unsigned char`, only those values that can be read through `getchar` (which need not span the entire range of `unsigned char`). On PDP-10, where `CHAR_BIT == 36`, `sizeof(char)` indeed equals `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Jamesdlin:For unsigned char, all bits are required to participate in the value representation (i.e. no padding bits, signaling bits, etc., are allowed. This means for unsigned char, the range *must* be defined directly by the number of bits. For int that's not required. In theory, that would mean it could use the same number of bits, but have a smaller range, except that having a smaller range is directly prohibited.

Comment: @avakar:Sorry, but no. The standard specifically requires that you can any stream of unsigned chars, write them to a file, and get the same values when you read them back. Thus, you must be able to read any value of unsigned char with getchar(). As an aside, I never heard of an implementation of C for the PDP-10 that used 36-bit chars. Most used 7-bit chars, stored 5 per word. That's enough for ASCII, but not the standard -- but I doubt there was ever a conforming implementation of C for the PDP-10.

Comment: @avakar is correct in that this is not guaranteed to work: it is possible to have `sizeof(int) == 1` and have all `int` values be valid character returns from `getchar()`, in which case `EOF` can also be a valid character, and testing whether `EOF` indicates end-of-file needs to be performed with `feof()` (and testing for error with `ferror()`). And Crays are an example of `sizeof(int) == 1`: they used to have all the integer types be 64 bits wide.

Comment: @jlk:Like I said, in theory, it's sort of correct. In reality, an implementation chars the same size as ints would break so much code nobody would ever use it. As far as Crays go, the idea of all integer types having the same size is an urban legend -- a rumor that remains widespread despite repeated testing showing that if it was ever true, it was only with a compiler that was never released to the outside world (and no evidence that it ever existed internally either).

Comment: @Jerry: See also my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's another answer:

```
char x[sizeof(char *)+2], y[1];
printf("%.*s\n", sizeof(1?x:y)-sizeof(char *)+1, "C++");
```

Comment: I tried compiling using gcc and g++ following code http://pastebin.com/zsxX1NNN The files were saves as foo.c and foo.cpp respectively. It printed C both times. I don't think that the way you did it should work, because size of pointers depends on the architecture.

Comment: Perhaps my idea was wrong. I thought the array would not decay to a pointer in C++ in this context...

Answer (score -1):

You could try preprocessor directives, but that might not be what they are looking for.