# Can sizeof(int) ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?

Tags: c

My view is that a C implementation cannot satisfy the specification of certain `stdio` functions (particularly `fputc`/`fgetc`) if `sizeof(int)==1`, since the `int` needs to be able to hold any possible value of `unsigned char` or `EOF` (-1). Is this reasoning correct?

(Obviously `sizeof(int)` cannot be 1 if `CHAR_BIT` is 8, due to the minimum required range for `int`, so we're implicitly only talking about implementations with `CHAR_BIT>=16`, for instance DSPs, where typical implementations would be a freestanding implementation rather than a hosted implementation, and thus not required to provide `stdio`.)

**Edit**: After reading the answers and some links references, some thoughts on ways it might be valid for a hosted implementation to have `sizeof(int)==1`:

First, some citations:

7.19.7.1(2-3):

> If the end-of-ﬁle indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
>   next character is present, the fgetc function obtains that character as an unsigned
>   char converted to an int and advances the associated ﬁle position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).
>
> If the end-of-ﬁle indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-ﬁle, the endof-ﬁle indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF. Otherwise, the
>   fgetc function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream.
>   If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function
>   returns EOF.

7.19.8.1(2):

> The fread function reads, into the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements
>   whose size is speciﬁed by size, from the stream pointed to by stream. For each
>   object, size calls are made to the fgetc function and the results stored, in the order
>   read, in an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object. The ﬁle position
>   indicator for the stream (if deﬁned) is advanced by the number of characters successfully read.

Thoughts:

- Reading back `unsigned char` values outside the range of `int` could simply have <strike>undefined</strike> implementation-defined behavior in the implementation. This is particularly unsettling, as it means that using `fwrite` and `fread` to store binary structures (which while it results in nonportable files, is supposed to be an operation you can perform portably on any single implementation) could appear to work but silently fail. <strike>essentially always results in *undefined behavior*. I accept that an implementation might not have a usable filesystem, but it's a lot harder to accept that an implementation could have a filesystem that automatically invokes nasal demons as soon as you try to use it, and no way to determine that it's unusable.</strike> Now that I realize the behavior is implementation-defined and not undefined, it's not quite so unsettling, and I think this might be a valid (although undesirable) implementation.
- An implementation `sizeof(int)==1` could simply define the filesystem to be empty and read-only. Then there would be no way an application could read any data written by itself, only from an input device on `stdin` which could be implemented so as to only give positive `char` values which fit in `int`.

**Edit (again):** From the C99 Rationale, 7.4:

> EOF is traditionally -1, but may be any negative integer, and *hence distinguishable from any valid character code*.

This seems to indicate that `sizeof(int)` may not be 1, or at least that such was the intention of the committee.

Comment: even if sizeof(char) == sizeof(int), are ints and chars required to represent the same range ? i.e. could a system provide a 16 bit char which you're only guaranteed to be able to use ,say,8 bit values, while an int makes use of all 16 (or - CHAR_MAX being less than INT_MAX, etc.) ?

Comment: @nos: No. `sizeof()` is in terms of `unsigned char` units, which are the fundamental representation of any type. See "Representation of Types" (6.2.6) in the C standard. The other direction is possible, though; some bits of `int` could be padding bits, trap bits, etc.

Comment: @nos: I take that back. If `sizeof(int)` is 1, `int` cannot have any padding bits/trap bits due to the integer conversion rank and promotion rules in 6.3.1.1. Specifically, paragraph 3 says "The integer promotions preserve value including sign." This also means that if `sizeof(int)` is 1 and `signed char` is twos complement, `int` must also be twos complement (or `SCHAR_MIN` could not be preserved by promotion).

Comment: @R: If sizeof(int) is one, 'int' could have extra padding/trap bits iff those same padding/trap bits exist for 'char'.  Likewise, if sizeof(int) is not one, a 'char' may have extra padding bits if such bits also serve as padding in larger types.  For example, a machine with 13-bit memory and registers could 'pretend' to be an 8-bit machine, if the unused bits did not affect the behavior of any legitimate program.

Comment: @supercat: Padding/trap bits for `char` *do not exist* as far as the formal language is concerned. That doesn't mean they're not there in the hardware. It means they're unobservable and therefore irrelevant.

Comment: @R: They would be unobservable in any legitimate program.  That does not mean that they would might not have effects on an illegitimate program.  For example, an implementation which uses parity-checked memory could deliberately mis-set the parity bits on any memory holding uninitialized data, or an which was more focused on correctness than efficiency could tag every byte in an array with the address of its 'base', allowing for precise trapping of out-of-bounds access.  A legitimate program would never see such things, but that wouldn't mean they'd be of no interest to a programmer.

Comment: @R: Also, I'd expect that a hardware implementation which e.g. only had 64-bit floating-point maths could decide act like a C implementation with a 51-bit char/int/long type, if all "unsigned" integer operations were done on such quantities, and all divisions  were truncated.  Signed integer operations could simply be done on floats directly, provided they were truncated, since accessing a signed int outside its defined range is UB.  Is there any requirement that the maximum "defined" range for a signed type be smaller than for unsigned?

Comment: @supercat: there would be no way even for an illegitimate program to see or write such "padding bits". You seem to be assuming the existence of an `asm` keyword or other way of writing machine code, which is outside the scope of the C language. There would be **absolutely no way**, using just C code, to access such padding bits in `char`, so from a formal standpoint, they don't exist.

Comment: Regarding your float-based implementation, even if the range of signed types is required to be smaller than the range for unsigned types, you just declare it as smaller in `limits.h`. Behavior on overflow is **undefined**, so it doesn't matter if larger values somehow get generated.

Comment: @R: An implementation could provide certain means of writing such bits via C code, in data which a legitimate program would be forbidden from reading.  You are correct in noting that because undefined behavior is precisely that, a bit which can only be read using undefined behavior does not, from a standards standpoint, exist.  Nonetheless, since it may be desirable to have an implementation ensure that undefined behavior won't cause nasal demons, even though the spec doesn't require it, having extra bits could sometimes be useful.

Comment: @R: BTW, I've sometimes thought it would be useful for a C compiler to offer 'unchecked' unsigned types, whose out-of-range behavior would be explicitly UB.  That would variables to have a shorter type in RAM than in registers--a useful optimization for RAM-conscious code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is possible for an implementation to meet the interface requirements for `fgetc` and `fputc` even if `sizeof(int) == 1`.

The interface for `fgetc` says that it returns the character read as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`. Nowhere does it say that this value cannot be `EOF` even though the expectation is clearly that valid reads "usually" return positive values. Of course, `fgetc` returns `EOF` on a read failure or end of stream but in these cases the file's error indicator or end-of-file indicator (respectively) is also set.

Similarly, nowhere does it say that you can't pass `EOF` to `fputc` so long as that happens to coincide with the value of an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`.

Obviously the programmer has to be very careful on such platforms. This is might not do a full copy:

```
void Copy(FILE *out, FILE *in)
{
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, out);
}
```

Instead, you would have to do something like (not tested!):

```
void Copy(FILE *out, FILE *in)
{
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF || (!feof(in) && !ferror(in)))
        fputc(c, out);
}
```

Of course, platforms where you will have real problems are those where `sizeof(int) == 1` and the conversion from `unsigned char` to `int` is not an injection. I believe that this would necessarily the case on platforms using sign and magnitude or ones complement for representation of signed integers.

Comment: Passing `EOF` to `fputc` is completely valid because the argument is converted to `unsigned char` before being written. Thus `fputc(EOF)` is equivalent to `fputc(UCHAR_MAX)`. The conversion in the other direction, however, is undefined behavior if `UCHAR_MAX>INT_MAX`.

Comment: @R..: Yes, you're completely correct about passing `EOF` to `fputc`. Then conversion from an `unsigned char` that can't be represented as an `int` value to `int` does not cause _undefined behaviour_, though, it is _implementation defined_. This is important because it allows an implementation to support the `fputc`/`fgetc` round trip.

Comment: You are correct. I assumed the behavior was the same as signed arithmetic overflow, but conversion to a signed type is implementation-defined (according to 6.3.1.3 paragraph 3) as you say.

Answer (score 10):

I remember this exact same question on comp.lang.c some 10 or 15 years ago. Searching for it, I've found a more current discussion here:

http://groups.google.de/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/9047fe9cc86e1c6a/cb362cbc90e017ac

I think there are two resulting facts:

(a) There can be implementations where strict conformance is not possible. E.g. sizeof(int)==1 with one-complement's or sign-magnitude negative values or padding bits in the int type, i.e. not all unsigned char values can be converted to a valid int value.

(b) The typical idiom `((c=fgetc(in))!=EOF)` is not portable (except for CHAR_BIT==8), as EOF is not required to be a separate value.

Comment: @R..: Ah, now I see. `fputc` couldn't work in my solution without "encoding" the character. So that excludes binary streams, but that's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe the C standard directly requires that EOF be distinct from any value that could be read from a stream. At the same time, it does seem to take for granted that it will be. Some parts of the standard have conflicting requirements that I doubt can be met if EOF is a value that could be read from a stream.

For example, consider `ungetc`. On one hand, the specification says (§7.19.7.11):

> The ungetc function pushes the character specified by c (converted to an unsigned
>   char) back onto the input stream pointed to by stream. Pushed-back characters will be
>   returned by subsequent reads on that stream in the reverse order of their pushing.
>   [ ... ]
>   One character of pushback is guaranteed.

On the other hand, it also says:

> If the value of c equals that of the macro EOF, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged.

So, if EOF is a value that could be read from the stream, and (for example) we do read  from the stream, and immediately use `ungetc` to put EOF back into the stream, we get a conundrum: the call is "guaranteed" to succeed, but also explicitly required to fail.

Unless somebody can see a way to reconcile these requirements, I'm left with considerable doubt as to whether such an implementation can conform.

In case anybody cares, [N1548](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (the current draft of the new C standard) retains the same requirements.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Would it not be sufficient if a nominal `char` which shared a bit pattern with `EOF` was defined as non-sensical? If, for instance, CHAR_BIT was 16 but all the allowed values occupied only the 15 least significant bits (assume a 2s-complement of sign-magnitude int representation). Or must everything representable in a `char` have meaning as such? I confess I don't know.</s>

Sure, that would be a weird beast, but we're letting our imaginations go here, right?

R.. has convinced me that this won't hold together. Because a hosted implementation must implement `stdio.h` and if `fwrite` is to be able to stick integers on the disk, then `fgetc` could return any bit pattern that would fit in a `char`, and that must not interfere with returning EOF. QED.

Comment: If a file is opened in binary mode, any value of `unsigned char` must be able to be written to and read back from the file. And `unsigned char` cannot have padding bits.

Comment: Hmm... ::sits and considers various ways to try and save the idea::

Comment: ...but no. I think that's me told. I withdraw the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so familiar with C99, but I don't see anything that says `fgetc` must produce the full range of values of `char`. The obvious way to implement stdio on such a system would be to put 8 bits in each `char`, regardless of its capacity. The requirement of `EOF` is

> `EOF`
>
> which expands to an integer
>   constant expression, with type int and
>   a negative value, that is returned by
>   several functions to indicate
>   end-of-file, that is, no more input
>   from a stream

The situation is analogous to `wchar_t` and `wint_t`. In 7.24.1/2-3 defining `wint_t` and `WEOF`, footnote 278 says

> `wchar_t` and `wint_t` can be the same integer type.

which would seem to guarantee that "soft" range checking is sufficient to guarantee that `*EOF` is not in the character set.

### Edit:

This wouldn't allow binary streams, since in such a case `fputc` and `fgetc` are required to perform no transformation. (7.19.2/3) Binary streams are not optional; only their distinctness from text streams is optional. So it would appear that this renders such an implementation noncompliant. It would still be perfectly usable, though, as long as you don't attempt to write binary data outside the 8-bit range.

Comment: You mean "8 **bits** in each char", right? In C, a byte has CHAR_BIT bits. And `wchar_t` has the same requirements as `char`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Great compression scheme ;) I'm not sure if this 'fixes' it. I haven't found anything that forbids it yet.

Comment: @schot: Well… it seems necessary to interoperability with files that aren't pre-padded. The alternative isn't actually any less dense; you need to address those ASCII characters somehow.

Comment: I mean more dense. Wow, I should quit for the evening.

Comment: If you only put 8 bits in each `char`, then `CHAR_BIT==8` and we're outside the domain of the question. Now it's very possible that someone using an implementation with `CHAR_BIT==64` would still only want to store 8 bits in each `char` when dealing with text data (in ASCII or UTF-8, for example), but this does not change the fact that `char` is an integer type capable of representing its entire range, and that `fgetc` and `fputc` work on binary data.

Comment: The value of `WEOF` is implementation-defined. The value of `EOF` is -1.

Comment: Actually both are implementation-defined, but `EOF` is required to be negative, while `WEOF`'s sign is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right. Such an implementation cannot distinguish a legitimate unsigned char value from EOF when using `fgetc`/`fputc` on binary streams.

If there are such implementations ([this thread](http://www.dsprelated.com/groups/code-comp/show/591.php) seems to suggest there are), they are not *strictly* conforming. It is possible to have a *freestanding* implementation with `sizeof (int) == 1`.

A freestanding implementation (C99 4) only needs to support the features from the standard library as specified in these headers: <float.h>, 
<iso646.h>, <limits.h>, <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stddef.h>, and 
<stdint.h>. (Note no <stdio.h>). Freestanding might make more sense for a DSP or other embedded device anyway.

Comment: Nit: <float.h>, <iso646.h>, etc are not libraries: they are standard headers

Comment: @pmg Thanks, I've reworded the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the EOF cannot be an actual character in the character set.
If you allow this, then sizeof(int) == 1 is OK.

Comment: Is this allowed? I seriously doubt it. Citation either way?

Comment: `EOF` cannot be a value of `unsigned char`, as its value is -1. However, what may be possible (it's unclear to me) is whether the standard allows an implementation to have some values of `unsigned char` which cannot be represented in `int` (their conversion to `int`, which it specifies happens, would then have undefined behavior).

Comment: @R For citation check the C standard. `EOF` definitely isn't defined as `-1`. Signed to unsigned conversion isn't defined per standard but we are talking about specific platform here.

Comment: Signed to unsigned conversion is defined by the C standard. It's reduction modulo 2^N. Unsigned to signed conversion is defined by the standard when the value is representable; when it's not, the result is implementation-defined. Sorry about `EOF` and -1. It's a negative constant of type `int`, not necessarily -1, but that does not change the fact that it cannot be a value of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Just to revisit this answer, it appears to be correct because the assumption "EOF cannot be an actual character in the character set" *must* hold, per the above comments. The question is whether a value of `unsigned char`, outside the range of `int`, may alias `EOF` after the implementation-defined, overflow-oriented conversion. There's no reason it can't, and the accepted answer has more depth, but this deserves a vote.

Answer (score 1):

The TI C55x compiler I am using has a 16bit char and 16bit int and *does* include a standard library.  The library merely assumes an eight bit character set, so that when interpreted as a character as char of value > 255 is not defined; and when writing to an 8-bit stream device, the most significant 8 bits are discarded: For example when written to the UART, only the lower 8 bits are transferred to the shift register and output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not a conformant hosted implementation.

Comment: No, but it could be made one. :-)

Comment: From TI's documents: [*On targets where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` (C2700, C2800, C5400, C5500), you still can't reliably use the return value of `getc()` to check for end of file, because 0xffff will be mistaken for the end of file. Use `feof()` instead*](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/C89_Support_in_TI_Compilers#Misunderstandings_about_TI_C)

Comment: @phuclv possibly so in the current documentation and library. Not necessarily so in 2011 when this answer was written, and the compiler I was using was old even then.