# getchar() inconsistency with variables

Tags: c

So I'm reading K&R book and I have a question regarding this code:

```
int c;
c = getchar();
```

Why do they use integer variable? Isn't the value that getchar() returns a character? So a char would be more suitable? Please enlighten me.

Comment: The answer is in the K&R book itself, on the same page as the first occurrence of this code (page 16 in my copy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`getchar()` needs to be able to indicate when it's reached the end of the input.** It does this by returning `EOF`, which is deliberately outside the valid `char` range so it can't clash with a character appearing on the input.

Comment: +1 this is very sensible. But take a look at [a great question of R..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation). It seems `getc` *could* return `EOF` as a valid character (so `feof` must be tested).

Answer (score 3):

The `getchar` function is returning an `int` because it need a way to signal an error while trying to read from the file. As the `char` type is only required to hold all possible value of characters, you need a larger type to be able to return `EOF` value.

Answer (score 1):

This is so that when `getchar()` returns `EOF`, you can distinguish `EOF` from a real, valid `char`.

Answer (score 0):

getchar returns EOF (-1) when the input file is at eof.

Answer (score 0):

take a look
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5231d02a(VS.71).aspx

Comment: This is not an answer. Posting a link to the documentation on one implementation of `getchar` fails to answer the question.