# How do i enter an EOF character in this program?

Tags: c++, c, eof

i was studying EOF character in c and came across a program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int c= 0;
while((c = getchar())!=EOF)
putchar(c);
}
```

its all good it is giving proper o/p but how do i come out of the loop by entering a EOF character which i entered and it did nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [representing-eof-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389518/representing-eof-in-c-code)

Comment: If you are running this program on a linux terminal Cntrl+D should send EOF to the program. You can also use a pipe such as `echo "My Input" | ./program`.

Comment: Try Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z.

Comment: i am running this on command prompt

Comment: ctrl + z works so that means its an EOF char

Comment: possible duplicate of [End of File (EOF) in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stimulate `EOF` in `stdin`,

- If you are on windows or DOS press CTRL+Z
- Or if you are running linux or some other OS, press CTRL+D

Comment: Under some environments, it is necessary to enter CTRL-Z twice.   It is also usually best to precede the CTRL-Z (single or pair) or CTRL-D with the enter key, to avoid the last line of input being discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an EOF character,and CTRL+Z and CTRL+D are used to inform the OS for termination.
Follow these links it has the answers 
[Representing EOF in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389518/representing-eof-in-c-code)
[End of File (EOF) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)