# Taking input as array of words in c++

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word)
words.push_back(word);
cout<<words[1];
```

i am using this to take input to create an array of words with whitespaces.but after ending of sentence using Enter, i am not getting any output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Also a vector index starts at zero if you use the vectors at() method you may get an out of bounds exception...

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/zh6irX) for me.

Comment: May the upvoter explain please how this question is useful or well researched?

Comment: The enter key is just more whitespace, not eof.

Answer (score 2):

> i am using this to take input to create an array of words with whitespaces.but after ending of sentence using Enter, i am not getting any output.

That's because

```
while (std::cin >> word)
  words.push_back(word);
```

does not stop when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It stops when there is no more data in `std::cin`. You have to enter EOF to get out of the `while` loop.

Useful link: [How do i enter an EOF character in this program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380039/how-do-i-enter-an-eof-character-in-this-program).

Comment: using cin will not allow to input words with spaces, as mentioned in the question

Comment: @RamakanthPutta, I think the OP wants to read words separated by whitespaces, not words with embedded whitespaces.

Comment: Yes, Might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
getline(cin,word)
```

instead of

```
cin<<word
```

will allow you to input words with whitespaces.

Even, vector starts at index 0, hence output

```
words[0]
```

instead of

```
words[1]
```

will output the entered value. that is the problem.