# Why unsigned char variable contains EOF?

Tags: c, eof

I developed an encryption algorithm which takes character by character texts from a .txt file and encrypts it, and then writes it back to another .txt file. The problem is when I read the encrypted file, a character like arrow sign acts as EOF and my loop terminates before the original EOF. Here is my code:

```
static void ECB_ENCRYPTION(void)
{
    uint8_t i = 0, j = 0, c, buf1[16]


    uint8_t plain_text[16];

    // File pointers for file operations.
    FILE *f, *f1;


    // Encrypts the file [plaintext.txt].
    f = fopen("plaintext.txt", "r");
    f1 = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "w");
    while(1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while(i < 16)
        {
            c = getc(f);
            if(feof(f))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                plain_text[i] = c;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        if(i != 16)
        {
            while(i < 16)
            {
                plain_text[i] = ' ';
                ++i;
            }
        }

        // Encrypts plain text.
        AES128_ENCRYPT(plain_text, buf1);

        i = 0;
        while(i < 16)
        {
            putc(buf1[i], f1);
            ++i;
        }

        if(feof(f))
            break;

    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(f1);
}

static void ECB_DECRYPTION(void)
{

    uint8_t i = 0, j = 0, c, buf1[16];

    uint8_t cipher_text[16];

    // File pointers for file operations.
    FILE *f, *f1;

    // Encrypts the file [plaintext.txt].
    f = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "r");
    f1 = fopen("decryptedtext.txt", "w");
    while(1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while(i < 16)
        {
            c = getc(f);
            if(feof(f))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cipher_text[i] = c;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        if(feof(f))
            break;

        // Decrypts cipher text.
        AES128_DECRYPT(cipher_text, buf1);

        i = 0;
        while(i < 16)
        {
            putc(buf1[i], f1);
            ++i;
        }

    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing EOF in C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389518/representing-eof-in-c-code)

Comment: "Arrow sign" doesn't sound like text. Perhaps you should treat the encrypted file as binary and `fopen` it using  `"wb"` and `"rb"`.

Comment: An example of the inputs causing the problems would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: I used feof() function to identify the end of my file but it fails at a character like -> arrow and my loop ends before the end of file

Comment: Follow Klas's advice and open in binary mode. Text mode (often the default in Windows) can be helpful if you are treating a file as text (it smooths over the differences between different systems' ideas of what a "text file" looks like) but is irrelevant when encrypting, when you pretty much want to treat everything as just a collection of bytes.

Comment: [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714)

Comment: Why don't you use the correct type for `c`? `getc` returns an `int`, not an `uint8_t`, i.e. `unsigned char`! Don't wonder if you get unexpected results if you don't follow the rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `uint8_t c` rather than `int c` obfuscated the true issue: opening the file in binary vs. text mode.  [@Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978923/why-unsigned-char-variable-contains-eof/43980034#comment74987185_43978923)

`int c` would have been better.  Still OP's use of `uint8_t; c = getc(f); if(feof(f))` was *almost* correct.  It fails when an read error occurs.

```
static void ECB_DECRYPTION(void) {
    uint8_t cipher_text[16];
    uint8_t buf1[16];

    FILE *f = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "rb");  // add 'b'
    assert(f);
    FILE *f1 = fopen("decryptedtext.txt", "wb"); // add 'b'
    assert(f1);
    while(1)
    {
        int c;
        for (unsigned i=0; i<16; i++) {
            c = getc(f);
            if (c == EOF) break;
            cipher_text[i] = (uint8_t) c;
        }

        if(c == EOF) break;  // exit loop on end-of-file or input error

        AES128_DECRYPT(cipher_text, buf1);

        for (unsigned i=0; i<16; i++) {
            putc(buf1[i], f1);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because an encrypted ascii character can get any binary representation, including nul, EOF, ^Z or whatever. So your resulting encrypted file is no longer a text file. It is now a binary file.

So when creating the encrypted file, open it with `"wb"` and when reading it, open it with `"rb"`. Also, use binary functions to write (`fwrite`) and read (`fread`), not `fputc` and `fegtc`.

Comment: A `uint8_t c` cannot have the value of `EOF`, a negative number.