# is it possible to make input() throw errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> input("input")
input>? a
'a'
>>> input("input")
input>? 'a
"'a"
>>> input("input")
input>? '"a
'\'"a'
>>> input("input")
input>? \'"a
'\\\'"a'
>>> input("input")
input>? "'a
'"\'a'
>>> input("input")
input>? "''a
'"\'\'a'
```

It seems that whatever I throw in `input` in hopes to break it, python just keeps one upping me. It like knows what I'm trying to achieve here and goes "nope"

Comment: So, you are complaining that it works properly?

Comment: amusing question. no, its like expecting a string to break something. a string that is not being evaluated to be specific.

Comment: Why would it throw an error? It just registers what you type in. That's what it's for.

Comment: People need to cheer up. This is an interesting question. +1

Comment: its not that i'm complaining that it works properly, i'm just genually curiuous if its possible for it to break

Comment: the only thing I have in mind is to do ctrl + C for throw KeyboardInterupt exception, But this is a normal behavior.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that much of what your example is showing is the effect of `repr` on the returned string. Try using `print(input('input'))` in a loop and you will see that `input` always returns the same string that was typed in.

Comment: my initial idea was that `input` wraps input in `' '`, so first thought that came to mind if i can circumvent that, but then it just started wrapping input in `" "` and later attempts with `\`

Comment: It’s not wrapping anything. It returns a string. A string isn’t wrapped in quotes, a string just contains its contents, which is whatever you typed in. Only when you print a *string representation* will quotes come into play, and Python is perfectly capable of producing any valid string representation regardless of the string’s content.

Comment: @Konulv: `input` *never* wraps input in quotes or anything else. It just returns a string. `repr` (which the Python interactive prompt uses when printing things) attempts to construct a string which, when parsed by Python, would produce the same string it received as input. So what you're seeing here is the behavior of `repr`, nothing to do with `input` at all.

Comment: so you are saying i should be looking into how to break `repr`? xD @DanielPryden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EOFError mentioned by others can also be triggered by standard input being something that isn't an infinite stream (like standard input generally is), such as `/dev/null`:

```
$ python3 -c 'input("")' < /dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

In a similar vein, we could also write [input that's impossible to decode as UTF-8](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt) (here using `xxd` to decode hex into bytes that are then passed to Python).

```
$ echo 'fe fe ff ff' | xxd -r -ps | python3 -c 'print(input())'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which will trigger an `EOFError`.
Similary, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Demo:

```
>>> input('in: ')
in: Traceback (most recent call last): # <-- I pressed CTRL-D
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

Maybe a more interesting way to get the `EOFError` is to use an empty file as the input to your program.

```
$ cat input.py
got = input('in: ')
print(got)
$ echo some text > not_empty.txt
$ python3 input.py < not_empty.txt 
in: some text
$ touch empty.txt
$ python3 input.py < empty.txt 
in: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input.py", line 1, in <module>
    got = input('in: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* an answer to the question, but you can throw a `UnicodeDecodeError` by changing the default encoding in python and then trying to input a unicode character (such as an emoji) which follows a different encoding scheme.

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=ascii
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input('>>> ')
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on the question here, it appears that the actual confusion stems from how the Python interactive prompt displays the return value of `input`. The interactive session always displays values using `repr`, which is designed to try to print a string which, when parsed, would produce the original value. For strings this can lead to some confusion, since the thing that is printed in the interactive session is *not* the actual string, but a *representation* of the string.

To see the difference, you can try playing around with this program, which will likely be instructive:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unicodedata

def main():
    while True:
        s = input('Enter a string: ')
        if not s:
            break
        print('Got string with length {}'.format(len(s)))
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            print('Character {}: {}'.format(i, unicodedata.name(c)))
        print('repr() produces: {}'.format(repr(s)))
        print('String literally contains: {}'.format(s))
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are some examples of what it prints:

```
Enter a string: a
Got string with length 1
Character 0: LATIN SMALL LETTER A
repr() produces: 'a'
String literally contains: a

Enter a string: 'a
Got string with length 2
Character 0: APOSTROPHE
Character 1: LATIN SMALL LETTER A
repr() produces: "'a"
String literally contains: 'a

Enter a string: "a'
Got string with length 3
Character 0: QUOTATION MARK
Character 1: LATIN SMALL LETTER A
Character 2: APOSTROPHE
repr() produces: '"a\''
String literally contains: "a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Well Well,

Try this little bugger. 
[image]

Apparently you can raise EOF errors with the right symbol or with ctrl + D. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError)

Comment: purposefully inserts a pic so i cant get that character xD. Is there a good reason for that tho? like its not part of whats in ASCII table that python uses or something else?

Comment: Well, the issue is that i actually have that character pasted, but im guessing it does not carry over. You see that box next to my sentence `try this little bugger`? It's supposed to be there, but its apparently not or it gets lost in conversion when i paste it here :P @Konulv

Comment: @Konulv [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389518/representing-eof-in-c-code)

Comment: Yay for windows! thanks for the link @timgeb much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In that case, change the environment from python 3.0 to python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
text=input("Enter somthing that throws error!!!")
```

Then whatever you put it will throw an error, For instance, consider "dude" as a string then it throws the following error

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dude' is not defined
```