# Is it possible to confuse EOF with a normal byte value when using fgetc?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, binaryfiles, fgetc

We often use `fgetc` like this:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Theoretically, if a byte in the file has the value of `EOF`, this code is buggy - it will break the loop early and fail to process the whole file. Is this situation possible?

As far as I understand, `fgetc` internally casts a byte read from the file to `unsigned char` and then to `int`, and returns it. This will work if the range of `int` is greater than that of `unsigned char`.

What happens if it's not (probably then `sizeof(int)=1`)?

- Will `fgetc` read a legitimate data equal to `EOF` from a file sometimes?
- Will it alter the data it read from the file to avoid the single value `EOF`?
- Will `fgetc` be an unimplemented function?
- Will `EOF` be of another type, like `long`?

I could make my code fool-proof by an extra check:

```
int c;
for (;;)
{
    c = fgetc(file);
    if (feof(file))
        break;
    // do stuff
}
```

It is necessary if I want maximum portability?

Comment: No. The `if (feof()) {...}` is useless. The code inside the `{}` will never be reached. AFTER the QUESTION edit: `if (c == EOF) break;` is sufficient. no need to use `feof()`. after `c=fgetc()` c can be 0..0xff (assuming 8bit chars) for actual characters, **or** -1 for EOF (which is not a normal character.

Comment: You said it yourself: converts to `unsigned char` and then to `int`, so `0xFF` cannot be returned as `EOF`, `-1`. An `int` does not have a size of 1.

Comment: see [Can sizeof(int) ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation)

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p2

Comment: @cremno: Just to note that while `sizeof(int)` can be `1`, this does not imply identical ranges for `signed char` and `int` or their unsigned counterparts. A 24 bit platform might very well define a range of `0..255` for `unsigned char`, but `0..(1UL<<24)-1` for `int`. (e.g. 56300 DSPs).

Comment: The standard does not require `EOF` to be `-1`. It just has to be negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `c = fgetc(file); if (feof(file))` does work for maximum portability.  It works in general and also when the `unsigned char` and `int` have the same number of unique values.  This occurs on rare platforms with `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned` all using the same bit width and width of range.

Note that `feof(file))` is insufficient.  Code should also check for `ferror(file)`.

```
int c;
for (;;)
{
    c = fgetc(file);
    if (c == EOF) {
      if (feof(file)) break;
      if (ferror(file)) break;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Although this would be overkill on the *vast* majority of systems, based on the discussions in the other answers' comments, I am now convinced that this is the only 100% portable way to do it, and the idea of an actual *hosted* implementation with sizeof(int) == 1 will now forever haunt my nightmares.

Comment: @Ray agree with the overkill, nightmares, etc.  Truly robust C code is _hard_.

Comment: Note: `if (ferror(file)) break;` is a possible false-positive.  The file error flag may be set before this code and `c == EOF` is due to a `unsigned char` whose value converter to `int` is `EOF`.  (Only when `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`).  Then `ferror(file)` returns true due to the error flag's past history and without regard to the recent `fgetc()`: a _narrow_ hole.

Answer (score 5):

The C specification says that `int` must be able to hold values from -32767 to 32767 at a minimum. Any platform with a smaller `int` is nonstandard.

The C specification also says that `EOF` is a negative `int` constant and that `fgetc` returns "an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`" in the event of a successful read. Since `unsigned char` can't have a negative value, the value of `EOF` can be distinguished from anything read from the stream.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup>See below for a loophole case in which this fails to hold.

---

Relevant standard text (from C99):

- §5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`:

  > [The] implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > - minimum value for an object of type `int`
  >
  >   > `INT_MIN` -32767
  > - maximum value for an object of type `int`
  >
  >   > `INT_MAX` +32767
- §7.19.1 `<stdio.h>` - Introduction

  > `EOF` ... expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream
- §7.19.7.1 The `fgets` function

  > If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by `stream` is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined)

If `UCHAR_MAX` ≤ `INT_MAX`, there is no problem: all `unsigned char` values will be converted to non-negative integers, so they will be distinct from EOF.

Now, there *is* a funny sort of loophole here: if a system has  `UCHAR_MAX` > `INT_MAX`, then a system is legally allowed to convert values greater than `INT_MAX` to negative integers (per §6.3.1.3, the result of converting a value to a signed type that cannot represent that value is *implementation defined*), making it possible for a character read from a stream to be converted to EOF.

Systems with `CHAR_BIT > 8` do exist (e.g. the TI C4x DSP, which apparently uses 32-bit bytes), although I'm not sure if they are broken with respect to EOF and stream functions.

Comment: Ah, but `CHAR_BIT` can be bigger than 8, and for `CHAR_BIT >= 16` it's permissible for `sizeof(int)` to be 1.

Comment: Yuck, this is in fact a possible defect in the standard (albeit an extremely minor one).

Comment: Sure, but what if you have an embedded system or something that doesn't permit addressing at anything other than a word boundary?  Do you define int to be larger than a word?  Then you need multiple instructions to operate on a single int.  Do you define char to be smaller than a word?  You then need to store the char in a full word and use bitwise masking to get the part you need.  Either option is at least as ugly as having sizeof(int) == 1.  So the standard leaves it to the implementation to decide which option is least horrible.

Comment: @Ray: I'm not saying that `CHAR_BIT != 8` is bad; I'm saying that the standard apparently allows the possibility that a character read from a stream can be converted to `EOF`. (Note that the TI C4x DSP referenced in my answer has 32-bit everything, including `char`, `short`, `float`, `long`, `int`, `double`, except `long double` which is 40 bits).

Comment: Systems with `CHAR_BIT > 8` are very likely to be embedded systems, which means the C implementation is likely to be *freestanding*, which means that support for `<stdio.h>` is not required. It's certainly *possible* to have a hosted implementation with `CHAR_BIT > 8`, but given current systems it's not likely. (On the other hand, who knows what might become popular in a few decades.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I dare not think of the portability nightmare for general-purpose software on such a platform.

Comment: @EOF: I think you could check whether `fgetc()` returned `EOF` *and then* query `feof()` and `ferror()` to avoid false positives. If they both return false, then the apparent `EOF` returned by `fgetc()` is actually a valid character. Of course nobody bothers to do that, so existing code isn't portable to such systems.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I've worked with UNIX systems where `-1` is a valid system call return value...so you had to do `errno = EOK; ret = syscall(...); if(ret == -1 && errno != EOK) { ... }`

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh, I wasn't even talking about `EOF`. Just the sheer number of programs that assume `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float) == 4` or even (shudder) `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*) == 4`...

Comment: @EOF: Happily, the proliferation of 64-bit platforms is starting to erode that latter assumption (although in 20 years we might see people assume `sizeof(void *) == 8`...)

Comment: @nneonneo: I would think that could potentially vary for each system call.

Comment: @EOF This who recall 16-bit `int`, data pointer width != function pointer width do not make those "usual" assumptions.   These issues happened before and will occur again.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: chux's answer is the correct one in the most general case.  I'm leaving this answer up because I believe both the answer and the discussion in the comments are valuable in understanding the (rare) situations in which chux's approach is necessary.**

EOF is guaranteed to have a negative value (C99 7.19.1), and as you mentioned, fgetc reads its input as an unsigned char before converting to int.  So those by themselves guarantee that EOF can't be read from a file.

As for your specific questions:

- fgetc can't read a legitimate datum equal to EOF.  In the file, there's no such thing as signed or unsigned; it's just bit sequences.  It's C that interprets 1000 1111 differently depending on whether it's being treated as signed or unsigned. fgetc is required to treat it as unsigned, so negative numbers (other than EOF) cannot be returned.

  Addendum: It can't read EOF for the unsigned char part, but when it converts the unsigned char to an int, if the int is not capable of representing all values of the unsigned char, then the behavior is implementation-defined (6.3.1.3).
- fgetc is required by the standard for hosted implementations, but freestanding implementations are permitted to omit most of the standard library functions (some are apparently required, but I couldn't find the list.)
- EOF won't require a long, since fgetc needs to be able to return it and fgetc returns an int.
- As far as altering the data goes, it can't change the *value* exactly, but since fgetc is specified to read "characters" from the file as opposed to chars, it could potentially read in 8-bits at a time even if the system otherwise defines CHAR_BIT to be 16 (which is the minimum value it could have if sizeof(int) == 1, since INT_MIN <= -32767 and INT_MAX >= 32767 are required by 5.2.4.2).  In that case, the input *character* would be converted to a *unsigned char* that just always had its high bits 0.  Then it could make the conversion to int without losing precision.  (In practice, this just won't come up, since machines don't generally have 16-bit bytes)

Comment: No.  An `unsigned char` could be 32-bit as well as `int`, so all the `unsigned char` combinations map to some `int` value, leaving no unused `int` value for `EOF`.  On such systems `EOF` does overlay an `unsigned char` converted to `int`.

Comment: An implicit conversion isn't a bit-for-bit copy reinterpreted according to the new type.  There are a series of rules that specify how the value changes when converting between types.  In this case, we're converting to a signed type that can't represent the current value, so 6.3.1.3 applies and the value is implementation-defined or it raises an implementation-defined signal.  So you're right, overlaying EOF onto a valid int value is a *possibility*, but it's not guaranteed.  The good news is that the implementation is required to document what exactly happens at that point.

Comment: Agree. the salient issue is that an `unsigned char` converted to `int` _may_ have a negative value and it may equal `EOF`.