# C File read getchar yields random EOF after 32KB

Tags: c, ipc, file-handling

I was tasked to make a file copy over ipc shared memory. The problem is that getc randomly yeilds EOF after 32k char.

```
FILE* file;
int znak;

file = fopen("./source","r");

if(file != NULL)
{
    while(feof(file) == 0)
    {
        znak = getc(file);

        if(znak != EOF)
        {
            czekaj(0);
            *adres = znak;

            sygnal(1);
        }
    }

    wait(0);        //Wait for your turn
    *adres = EOF;
    signal(1);      //Let other process go
}
```

Writing part as requested

```
int znak
FILE *plik;
plik = fopen("./plik_klient", "w");
fclose(plik);

.....



plik = fopen("./result","a");


if(plik != NULL)
{
    while(znak != EOF)
    {

        wait(1);        //Opuszczenie semafora

        znak=*adres;

        if(znak != EOF)
        {
            fputc(znak,plik);

            signal(0);
        }

    }
}
```

As a result of work other process reads the info and writes it into file.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 ficekba inf-17   32769 01-11 21:15 result
-rw-r--r--. 1 ficekba inf-17 1000000 01-11 21:13 source
```

As you can see result file has exactly 32k

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong could be an interesting read for you.

Comment: So... "randomly" or "after 32K"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: what _type_ is `znak`.  Hopefully it is `int`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't think it is a duplicate...

Comment: "to make a file copy ", open in binary mode.  `fopen("./source","rb");`  Add b

Comment: @EugeneSh. by random i meant unexpected.

Comment: `char` can't have value of `EOF`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. OTOH `while(feof(file) == 0)` can lead to an infinite loop with a hard input error, yet I doubt that is OP's woes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. When `char` is signed and `EOF == -1` (this is common) , a `char` can have the value of `EOF`.  Still better to use `int znak`.

Comment: @chux _Still better to use int._ -> always use `int` would be better

Comment: @chux Well, yeah, incorrectly said. Surely always use, as when `char` equals to `-1` it is indistinguishable from a binary value read `0xFF`.

Comment: I've changed it to int but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: You don't show enough code. For example, where is the result written?

Comment: Post definition and use of `dres`.

Comment: You have both `signal` and `sygnal`, `wait` and `czekaj`... OK, [mcve] please, or VTC.

Comment: @Haito If comments answer to this point do not fix the issue, then it lies elsewhere and a more complete [mcve] with some of the bytes of `result` and `source` are needed.

Comment: Problem omited.. I've run that code on my Mac and it works flawlesly. Something is not quite happy with our University Shared server. That's good enough. Thank you very much all for help @EugeneSh.

Comment: the logic for the 'write' operation is a bit convoluted.  Also, there is an error.  The declaration of `znak` is leaving the variable containing what every value happens to be on the stack at that location.  That location might contain `0xFFFFFFFF`.   So this statement: `while(znak != EOF)` would immediately exit.  This is undefined behavior.  Suggest initializing `znak` to `0`.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, when the returned value is NULL, then call `perror()` so both the enclosed text AND the text giving the reason the system thinks the function failed are output to `stderr`

Comment: what is this call: `wait(1)` and this call: `signal(0)` expected to perform.  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the code

Answer (score 1):

Code uses `char znak` when `int znak` is best.

`getc()` returns an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  This is typically 257 different values: [-1 ... 255].  When code read the file `source` and may return a 255 and assigns that to a `char znak`, `znak` has the value of -1 which matches `EOF` in this case.  This fools code into thinking copying is done. and so may end up with a rump `result` file.

Use `int znak`.

---

Also open the file in binary mode is `source` may be a binary file.

```
// file = fopen("./source","r");
file = fopen("./source","rb");
```

Comment: Done, no effect

Comment: _Code uses char znak when int znak is best_ -> `int znak` is required

Comment: Yeah I've modified it.

Comment: @EdHeal `int znak` is not required - even though `int` is most often the best.  The value from `getc()` is in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  A type of `int` or `unsigned char/unsigned` should be used.  On select platforms where `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, there is a difficulty distinguishing end-of-file from character  `(unsigned char) EOF` and more complex code is needed.  Such code often uses `unsigned char/unsigned` for the stored return value of `getc()`.

Comment: Please `getc` returns an `int` - so Store it in an `int`. i.e. over 8 bits. `unsigned char` /`char` is (usually) 8 bits. Please tell me what platform that `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` is true

Comment: @EdHeal Do you agree `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` is allowed by the C spec? Else such a search and post would not be convincing.

Comment: @chux I think it is not allowed by C standard. UCHAR_MAX is required to be `2^CHAR_BITS - 1`, while I am pretty sure `int` is required to be wider than `char`....yet can't find by which clause...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not think C specifies  `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX`.  Some graphics processors have reported using `signed char, short, int` with the same signed  range as well as  `unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned` with a common unsigned range.  On such odd platforms `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.  Now if that C compliant - this remains unresolved. IAC, it is rare.

Comment: @EugeneSh. See [Is it possible to confuse EOF with a normal byte value when using fgetc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32641434/2410359)

Comment: @EugeneSh. This reports a sample of [all the integer types (< `long`) same size](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/implementations-with-char_bit-32.440062/#post-2435265).  C's very broad embrace of such odd (and now quaint) platforms appears to allow `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.  It is dubious if a future platform would attempt that given the common view that `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` is a truism.