# segment fault after parsing unsigned char to int pointer

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm facing a problem when trying to read a binary file of fixed size. The code below returns segmentation Fault just before closing the file. What I want to achieve it is to return an int pointer back to the main function.

The file it s a raw grayscale image, which has values from 0 to 255, that's why I'm using `unsigned char`.

How can I convert and assign from unsigned char to `*int` properly?

Any kind of help will be welcome!

```
void readBinaryFile(char *filename, int *in){

    FILE *file;
    long length;
    unsigned char *imagen;

    int c;

    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);

    imagen = (unsigned char *) malloc(length);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(imagen, length,  1 , file);

    int cont;
    //c+4: file contains values from 0 to 255 
    for(c=0,cont=0;c<length;c=c+4,cont++){
       in[cont] = (unsigned char) imagen[c];         
    }


    for(cont=0;cont<length/4;cont++){
       printf("%d",(int) in[cont]);
    }

    fclose(archivo);
    free(imagen_buffer);
}

void main(int argc, char **argv){

    int *in;           
    int fixed_size = 784;
    in = (int *) malloc((fixed_size)*(fixed_size));
    readBinaryFile("test.raw", in);

    int c;

    for(c=0;c<((fixed_size)*(fixed_size));c++){
        printf("%d", (unsigned char) in[c]);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int *in;
```

makes `in` point to an `int`.

This

```
 in = (int *) malloc((fixed_size)*(fixed_size));
```

allocates to `in` 784*784=614656 bytes.

1. You need 784*784 `int`s.
2. An `int` needs `sizeof (int)` bytes, which <strike>by definition is</strike> very well might be and most often is ***larger*** then 1.

From 1. and 2. above it can be deduces that 784*784 `int` needs *more* then 784*784 bytes.

So change

```
in = (int *) malloc((fixed_size)*(fixed_size));
```

to be

```
in = (int *) malloc((fixed_size)*(fixed_size) * sizeof (int));
```

or even nicer and safer with less noise do

```
in = malloc(fixed_size*fixed_size * sizeof *in);
```

because

- in C there is no need to cast `void*` (which `malloc()` returns).
- the parentheses around `fixed_size` are useless.
- using `sizeof *in` returns the same as `sizeof (int)`, but would "survive" if you changed `int * in` to become for example `unsigned * in`.

---

Also while reading you need to make sure to not read more then 784*784  `char`, as else the memory allocated for the `int` will be overflowed, which in turn invoked the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: dude,  I was stuck in this like all night, THANKS !

Comment: The size of `int` is not more than one by definition. It would have to be a derived property, as there is no such definition. However, by extensive discussion elsewhere on Stack Overflow, it may be possible for a conforming implementation to have `int` and `char` be the same size. (`EOF` is a troublesome issue for that.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil "*possible ...  to have `int` and `char` be the same size*" Really? I memorise the C Standard defining `CHAR_MAX` to be 127 or 255 as maximum and `INT_MAX` to be 32767 as minimum. Mind sharing the link to the discussion you mention?

Comment: @alk: The standard does not limit `CHAR_MAX` to being 127 or 255. There is discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, yes I see: Only the minimum values are defined by the Standard. My bad. Thank you for the correction.