# Can we mix c and c++ code

Tags: c++, c

I was reading this website

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

which is a C++ website.But, it uses printf to display things. However, i thought in c++, we use cout to display things. Can we mix c and C++ code as they have done here.

Comment: Yes, with care you can mix them.  No, it is usually not advisable.  Using `cout` gives you type safety that is missing from `printf()`, and also extensibility.  Use it.

Comment: cplusplus.com is known for errors in the documentation and examples.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why comment? That is a perfectly valid answer, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a program that will print "C" if compiled as an (ANSI) C program, and "C++" if compiled as a C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c)

Answer (score 7):

There is no mix of C++ and C code. While you certainly *can* use `cout` in C++, you can also use `printf`. The vast majority of things that are legal C code are also legal C++ code. In fact, section 27.8.2 of the C++ standard requires `printf` to be defined if your code `#include`'s `<cstdio>`.

Comment: do i need to include <cstdio> . Can't  i just include <stdio.h>

Comment: then what is the difference between the two

Comment: As far as `printf` goes, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, yes you ***can*** mix C and C++ code. C++ is a near super-set of C and has all of the C libraries (save for a few slight differences).

However, whether or not you ***should*** mix C and C++ is another story. Generally speaking, if you write in C++, you should stick to C++ constructs.

Comment: What do you mean by "stick to C++ constructs"? Is `printf` not a C++ construct? What about `int32_t`, is that a C++ construct?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to be pedantic. I was mainly referring to features added in C++ that duplicate existing C features. (`printf()`/`cout`, arrays/vectors, cstring/`string`) Not saying that they can't be used in C++ (and they have to in some cases), but C++ does make them easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C and C++ are (with very few exceptions) both possible and easy to mix. One example where you may have problems is mixing printf and cout, output may not come in the order you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the C-runtime is available since C++ is to a great degree compatible with C by design in order to be backwards compatible. That said, if you are programming C++ you should avoid using the C run-time as much as possible since C++ offers much more in terms of functionality and safety. e.g. vector, string

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! But make sure you're saving the code in a .cpp file. Some compilers wouldn't compile C++ code in a .c file.

Answer (score 1):

C++ contains (most of) C as a subset (although this isn't a strict subset). If you `#include <cstdio>` you can use things such as printf, however, unless you have a really good reason, you should stick with using C++ constructs (`std::vector, std::cout, new, delete,` etc).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can mix the 2 codes, but then the resultant code should be in C++ if you are reluctant to edit for compatibility with C. C++ is backward for most of the code

Answer (score 0):

To let the C++ compiler know that you are calling C code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void myCFunction();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```