# Symbol clashing of inner and outer structs, C++ vs C

Tags: c++, c

So, say I have the following C++ header, `testheader.h`:

```
struct mystruct
{
  struct myinnerstruct
  {
        int x;
  } astruct;
};

struct myinnerstruct
{
    int x;
};
```

and the following C++ source, `test.cpp`:

```
#include "testheader.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

g++ gives no issues during compile/link.

Now, if I have the same header, but instead of the C++ source, a C source file `test.c`:

```
#include "testheader.h"
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

And I compile with gcc, I get the following error:

```
error: redefinition of struct myinnerstruct
```

So, I gather that the scope of the C version is the translation unit, and the C++ version is block scoped? Can someone confirm this is the case, and maybe give me a reason of why it makes sense? I'm doing some mixing of C and C++ code, and this is giving me quite a bit of trouble.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: why not just remove the redefinition?

Comment: @stark : Because it's _not_ a redefinition (in C++), it's an entirely different type.

Comment: @stark As in rename the inner struct? In this trivial example, that is a clear solution.  But the code I'm actually working with is not that simple, and I don't have that flexibility, unfortunately.

Comment: An even cuter one is including, from a C++ program, a C header that has something like: `typedef struct my_struct { } my_struct;`

Comment: What I mean is just define myinnerstruct once, then use just the name inside mystruct.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.  Could you rephrase or elaborate? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C nested structs do not actually live in their parents scope. However in C++ they do- `teststruct::innerstruct` is a different type to `innerstruct`. This is to improve encapsulation in C++ code. Without this rule, no two types in the same namespace could define a nested `iterator` class, for example, which would be extremely bad.

C treats structs in plenty of other very silly ways, so it's no surprise that they did the wrong thing here. However, C does not otherwise allow type scoping and having a sane rule here would have introduced many additional concepts to the language- ultimately, it would have required the introduction of `namespace`s, which for some reason was never done.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So this weird (IMO) C scoping issue is limited to structures? Does that explain why I can declare a variable `x` in a C `main`, and then have `main` call `myfunc`, which also declares a variable `x`, and gcc is happy?

Comment: If namespaces were introduced, I believe they would have to also introduce name mangling in C, which would cause many problems.

Comment: @Jesse: Not necessarily. It is templates and overloading that genuinely introduce name mangling problems. Namespaces alone can be trivially mangled- and have a defined mangling, which would not be problematic at all.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the definition of inner struct goes outside of the outer struct, which is not the case in C++.

This has been explained in this blog: [Incompatibilities Between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-nested-struct)
among many other things in *C vs. C++* with a reference to C99 and c++98 ISO standards.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for the link as well.  I was looking for something just like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are no scopes in C, so everything is in the "global" namespace (in C++ speak)

Comment: Ok, then my next question would be, why can I declare a variable `x` in a C `main`, and then have `main` call `myfunc`, which also declares a variable `x`, and all is okay? Why is there no symbol clashing there?

Comment: Because we are talking about scope of types here, not of variables

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way which works in bot C and C++ is:

```
struct myinnerstruct
{
    int x;
};

struct mystruct
{
  struct myinnerstruct astruct;
};
```

Comment: Only "works" in C++ if `::myinnerstruct` and `mystruct::myinnerstruct` are intended to be the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The issue is that I cannot change the definition or even any of that header file at all.

Comment: @Robᵩ if they aren't the same type, then it doesn't work in C no matter what.  If you don't have a C header, you need to write in C++