# sizeof operator returns different values for c & c++?

Tags: c++, c

A character array is defined globally and a structure with same name is defined within a function. Why sizeof operator returns different values for c & c++ ?

```
char S[13];
void fun()
{
    struct S
    {
        int v;
    };
    int v1 = sizeof(S);
}
```

// returns 4 in C++ and 13 in C

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Compiles fine on my compiler

Comment: @Ashwyn - your compiler compiles without the `;` after `struct S`'s declaration?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: oops sorry! forgot to write that, actually I wrote that code, instead of copy pasting!

Comment: I think the best answer in general is "Because C and C++ are different languages."

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c to see other silent differences between C and C++.

Comment: @Ashwyn I have no idea why it returns `4` in C++; you did `sizeof(S)` (13), not `sizeof(struct S)` (4).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because in C++, the `struct` you defined is named `S`, while in C, it's named `struct S` (which is why you often see `typedef struct` used in C code). If you were to change the code to the following, you would get the expected results:

```
char S[13];
void fun()
{
    typedef struct tagS
    {
        int v;
    } S;
    int v1 = sizeof(S);
}
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use names starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, because those names are [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/) for the implementation.

Comment: Fair enough. Modified slightly (not that it matters a whole lot for the sake of the example.)

Answer (score 10):

In C, to refer to the struct type, you need to say `struct S`.  Therefore, `sizeof(S)` refers to the array.

In C++, `struct` is unnecessary.  So the local `S` hides the global `S`.

Comment: That's why C++ is terrible.