# Temporary structure object constructor odd call

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I don't understand this code which should provide a different behavior in C and C++ ( [Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile))

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct f { };

int main() {
    f();
}

int f() {
    return printf("hello");
}
```

Why can I call f() in C++? Is it the default constructor (which I don't see by the way, is there another one "implicit"?)? In C++ that is not calling the f() function..

Comment: That's _value-initializing_ an instance of `f` then immediately destroying it, and yes, there is an implicitly-generated default constructor for `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class has an implicit default constructor, unless you define other constructor. This definition of the class `f`:

```
struct f { };
```

Is equivalent to:

```
struct f { 
    f() = default;
    // same for copy constructors, move constructors, destructor, etc
};
```

So yes, inside main, you're value initializing(or default initializing, it's the same here), an object of type `f`.

As of why it's not calling the function `f`, well, inside `main` there is no declaration nor definition of the function `f` available. The only visible symbol named `f` is the struct defined above.

Comment: Is it allowed to define a function with the same name as a struct?

Comment: The expression `f()` is **not** a call to the constructor. It is *value-initialization* of a temporary object. The difference is that for a POD type `f()` guarantees that all fields are *zero-initialized*, but the implicitly-defined default constructor would leave the fields uninitialized.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the "is equivalent to" should also have copy constructor, move assignment, destructor, etc?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas at no point did I state that `f()` is a call to a constructor. Or am I missing something in my answer?

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, well, my answer was regarding only default constructors, but you're right.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the expression `T()` where `T` is a type is the creation of a temporary that is *value-initialized*. Note that this is different from a call to the constructor in general (in particular it is different for POD types).