# std::isinf does not work with -ffast-math. how to check for infinity

Tags: c++, std, fast-math

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

static bool my_isnan(double val) {
    union { double f; uint64_t x; } u = { val };
    return (u.x << 1) > (0x7ff0000000000000u << 1);
}

int main() {
    cout << std::isinf(std::log(0.0)) << endl;
    cout << std::isnan(std::sqrt(-1.0)) << endl;
    cout << my_isnan(std::sqrt(-1.0)) << endl;
    cout << __isnan(std::sqrt(-1.0)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/848a529540ee5b5d).

With `-ffast-math`, that code prints "0, 0, 1, 1" -- without, it prints "1, 1, 1, 1".

Is that correct? I thought that `std::isinf`/`std::isnan` should still work with `-ffast-math` in these cases.

Also, how can I check for infinity/NaN with `-ffast-math`? You can see the `my_isnan` doing this, and it actually works, but that solution is of course very architecture dependent. Also, why does `my_isnan` work here and `std::isnan` does not? What about `__isnan` and `__isinf`. Do they always work?

With `-ffast-math`, what is the result of `std::sqrt(-1.0)` and `std::log(0.0)`. Does it become undefined, or should it be NaN / -Inf?

Related discussions: [(GCC) [Bug libstdc++/50724] New: isnan broken by -ffinite-math-only in g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50724), [(Mozilla) Bug 416287 - performance improvement opportunity with isNaN](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416287)

Comment: I think it will depends on the compiler and possibly OS you are using. With `clang` 5.1 on OS X, your sample code prints `1`.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne: Yea, but the question is mostly: How can I make the check in a way that it always works?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to print `std::log(0.0)` to see whether `std::log` or `std::isinf` computes the wrong result.

Comment: your my_isnan is not correct: `my_isnan(45.0) == 1`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier What hardware is that? I guess the `my_isnan` is only for x86-64 or so.

Comment: @Albert  x64 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5PaKazsja

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Hm yes. I don't know where this comes from. I think it should be `(u.x << 1) > (0x7ff0000000000000u << 1)`.

Comment: Here's a try for a safer version: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ET3rcx6b8

Comment: I opened a question on codereview to leverage the hive mind: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272093/checking-for-nan-bit-patterns-in-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that `-ffast-math` may make the compiler ignore/violate IEEE specifications, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options :

> This option is not turned on by any -O option besides -Ofast since it
>   can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact
>   implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions.
>   It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require
>   the guarantees of these specifications.

Thus, using `-ffast-math` you are not guaranteed to see infinity where you should.

In particular, `-ffast-math` turns on `-ffinite-math-only`, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath which means (from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options )

> [...] optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs

This means, by enabling the `-ffast-math` you make a promise to the compiler that your code will never use infinity or NaN, which in turn allows the compiler to optimize the code by, e.g., replacing any calls to `isinf` or `isnan` by the constant `false` (and further optimize from there). If you break your promise to the compiler, the compiler is not required to create correct programs.

Thus the answer quite simple, if your code may have infinities or NaN (which is strongly implied by the fact that you use `isinf` and `isnan`), you cannot enable `-ffast-math` as else you might get incorrect code.

Your implementation of `my_isnan` works (on some systems) because it directly checks the binary representation of the floating point number. Of course, the processor still might do (some) actual calculations (depending on which optimizations the compiler does), and thus actual NaNs might appear in memory and you can check their binary representation, but as explained above, `std::isnan` might have been replaced by the constant `false`. It might equally well happen that the compiler replaces, e.g., `sqrt`, by some version that doesn't even produce a NaN for input `-1`. In order to see which optimisations your compiler does, compile to assembler and look at that code.

To make a (not completely unrelated) analogy, if you're telling your compiler your code is in C++ you can not expect it to compile C code correctly and vice-versa (there are actual examples for this, e.g. [Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile) ).

It is a bad idea to enable `-ffast-math` and use `my_isnan` because this will make everything very machine- and compiler-dependent you don't know what optimizations the compiler does overall, so there might be other hidden problems related to the fact that you are using non-finite maths but tell the compiler otherwise.

A simple fix is to use `-ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only` which would still give some optimizations.

It also might be that your code looks something like this:

1. filter out all infinities and NaNs
2. do some finite maths on the filtered values (by this I mean maths that is guaranteed to never create infinities or NaNs, this has to be very, very carefully checked)

In this case, you could split up your code and either use optimize `#pragma` or `__attribute__` to turn `-ffast-math` (respectively `-ffinite-math-only` and `-fno-finite-math-only`) on and off selectively for the given pieces of code (however, I remember there being some trouble with some version of GCC related to this) or just split your code into separate files and compile them with different flags. Of course, this also works in more general settings if you can isolate the parts where infinities and NaNs might occur. If you can not isolate these parts, this is a strong indication that you can not use `-ffinite-math-only` for this code.

Finally, it's important to understand that `-ffast-math` is not a harmless optimization that simply makes your program faster. It does not only affect the performance of your code but also its correctness (and this on top of all the issues surrounding floating point numbers already, if I remember right [William Kahan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan) has a collection of horror stories on his homepage, see also [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). In short, you might get faster code, but also wrong or unexpected results (see below for an example). Hence, you should only use such optimizations when you really know what you are doing and you have made absolutely sure, that either

1. the optimizations don't affect the correctness of that particular code, or
2. the errors introduced by the optimization are not critical to the code.

Program code can actually behave quite differently depending on whether this optimization is used or not. In particular it can behave wrong (or at least very contrary to your expectations) when optimizations such as `-ffast-math` are enabled. Take the following program for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  double d = 1.0;
  double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  d /= max;
  d *= max;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

will produce output `1` as expected when compiled without any optimization flag, but using `-ffast-math`, it will output `0`.

Comment: I have extended my question a bit. Why does `my_isnan` work, and `std::isnan` does not?

Comment: So, a follow up question: With `-ffast-math`, what is the result of `std::sqrt(-1.0)` and `std::log(0.0)`. Does it become unspecified, or should it be NaN / -Inf?

Comment: @Albert: It reverts back to the standard, which is Undefined Behavior - anything may happen. "Unspecified" is too strong,

Comment: This is undefined, as by using `std::sqrt(-1.0)` you're breaking the requirement that you are using only finite values, i.e., no infinity or NaN. It might happen, that the compiler still generates "standard" code for `sqrt` and the actual computation yields `-inf` represented binary, but it might also happen that the compiler uses some different implementation of `sqrt` that can not handle input `-1`. Indeed, my version of GCC generates `call __sqrt_finite` rather than `call sqrt` when enabling `-ffast-math` (the latter seems to behave like the former, though, but this is not necessarily so).

Comment: What about `__isnan` and `__isinf`. Shouldn't they always work?

Comment: @Albert: Why should they work? If you need to use `__isnan` and `__isinf`, you are not using only finite maths, hence you can not enable `-ffast-math` (unless, of course, you like to be surprised by your code...). Of course you could probably write some custom `isnan`, etc. that still do what you want in the presence of `-fast-math` for a specific given compiler version and platform, but doing so would be horribly bad practice as your code might break with the next compiler update.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course I can enable `-ffast-math` and use `__isnan`. As far as I understand, `__isnan` is implemented in libm, which is compiled without `-ffast-math`, so it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean that you physically can't enable `-ffast-math` and use `__isnan`, but that it is very wrong to do, i.e., you should not do this exactly for the reason that using `__isnan` means using non-finite maths which excludes `-ffast-math` from being applicable. I haven't looked into the particulars of `__isnan`, but on my system it's just an alias for `isnan`, hence there's no difference. Am I right in assuming that you have some concrete problem where `-ffast-math` gives you a good optimization, but you still need `isnan`, etc.? Maybe it would be easier if you could post this?

Comment: @Albert I tried to add some more explanation and a possible solution. I hope that helps.

Comment: @godfatherofpolka: It's a very complex scientific framework which must use `-ffast-math` because of performance. However, it also has some rare occasions where NaN of Inf might still happen or where such number is returned by intention, and there must be a way to check if a float is such number. Are you sure `__isnan` is only an alias for you? What is the exact declaration? From what I have read, it is part of the binary specification of the C stdlib (specified by LSB), and I found it in most C stdlib implementations, e.g. glibc, dietlibc, uClibc, FreeBSD libc, sometimes in the separate libm.

Comment: @Albert I'm sorry, you're right about `__isnan`, I somehow must have made an error when compiling yesterday, I can't reproduce it. However, I think there is a deeper problem underlying this issue: If NaN or Inf can happen, using `-ffast-math` (or more specifically, `-ffinite-math-only`) may generate incorrect code, thus enabling it is completely wrong. As I have outlined above, you could try `-ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only`. If this does not yield sufficient performance, you need a different approach. I also added a warning about unsafe optimizations (even in the case without NaN and Inf).