# How can I enable -ffast-math with pragma in a bit old g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

For some reason, I want to enable "-ffast-math" via pragma in g++. 
But currently it doesn't work. 
It seems `#pragma GCC optimize("fast-math")` is eventually ignored although g++ recognizes it at least during parsing this pragma sentence.

Here is a snippet I used for checking this issue(borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22931368/12143880)):

```
#pragma GCC optimize("fast-math")
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  double d = 1.0;
  double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  d /= max;
  d *= max;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compiled this putting `-ffast-math` explicitly, this program outputs `0`:

```
$ g++ poc.cpp -ffast-math -Wall
$ ./a.out 
0
```

On the other hand, when I didn't put this flag, it shows 1 though I wrote the pragma sentence at least:

```
$ g++ poc.cpp -Wall
$ ./a.out 
1
```

Since I confirmed other optimizations such as `#pragma GCC optimize("O3")` work fine(I checked with objdump), I think somehow g++ ignores only `fast-math`.

Does anyone know the reason or have a workaround for this?

Here is the information of g++ in my environment:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
```

Comment: I did some tests with g++ 5.4 up to the trunk version and came to the same conclusion as you, that it's ignored.. :-/

Comment: Thank you for reporting that! So now I understand the version doesn't matter much...

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37565 or perhaps https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48026