# identifier "using" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have tried to add a new .cpp file into a C project in Visual Studio, with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the `#include <iostream>` alone produced 100+ errors, so I had to comment that to see if that was the problem. After doing so, this new error popped up: `identifier "using" is undefined`. I am guessing it is either because the project was somehow configured for C, or it is because there are things prepended to the file by the preprocessor that I am unaware of. How may I solve this?

Comment: As you say, your project is probably configured in C. Look at the project configuration in Visual Studio

Comment: This is `c++` code. It's not going to build as `c` code.

Comment: Rename the file's extension for C++ or go to the file's properties and tell the compiler to compile it as C++.  Some common C++ extensions: cpp, cc and C (capital letter on platforms that use case-sensitive filenames).

Comment: It turns out I need to change one setting: C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As. Thanks.

Comment: My advice is to select the correct file extension to avoid this issue.

Comment: I subscribe. By leaving the global settings blank, and giving the right extension to the file, you won't have to do this step every time when you add a new _.cpp_ file. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)'s how it works.

Comment: @TommyX, I hope that indeed works.  Be aware that C and C++ are distinct languages, each has features and syntax not supported by the other, and [***not all code that is valid in both has identical meaning in both***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile).  Be very careful, therefore, about compiling C code as if it were C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to add a new .cpp file into a C project in Visual Studio

You're aware that it's C++ code in a C project, good. There are differences between C and C++ that you should be aware of; C does not have `using namespace`, or `<iostream>`, or the `<<` operator (for printing at least), or `cout`.

If you want C++ files to work in your C project, you can either configure the project to compile as C++, convert your C++ file(s) to C code, or simply ensure that all C++ files have the `.cpp` extension (which would only work if the C project was on default settings).

Comment: This is not quite true. There can be projects with mixed (_C_ / _C++_) files. By naming the files properly (in terms of extensions: _.c_ / _.cpp_), and not messing with _VStudio_ __default__ settings (this is a general rule for inexperienced ones) it should work fine, with no further user interventions.

Comment: Well, C does have the `<<` operator, but only in its original meaning :)

Comment: You should try to keep your language neutral - do not assume and do not ask questions inorder to answer question, otherwise I agree with what you state