# Why does "sizeof(a ? true : false)" give an output of four bytes?

Tags: c, boolean, sizeof, conditional-operator, c11

I have a small piece of code about the `sizeof` operator with the ternary operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(bool));  // Ok
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));     // Ok
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false)); // Why 4?
    return 0;
}
```

**Output ([GCC](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/NE9Cfo)):**

```
1
1
4 // Why 4?
```

But here,

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false)); // Why 4?
```

the ternary operator returns `boolean` type and sizeof `bool` type is `1` byte in C.

Then **why does `sizeof(a ? true : false)` give an output of four bytes?**

Comment: `sizeof(true)` and `sizeof(false)` is also 4: http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/O5jvuN

Comment: if it is `C`, then its correct because `true` and `false` are integer constants

Comment: @vu1p3n0x note the wording "integer constant" doesn't require a specific integer type. `true` and `false` could be defined as `((char)1)` and `((char)0)`.

Comment: The more interesting question here would be why this implementation is "inconsistent" in that it obviously defines `_Bool` to have size 1, but not `true` and `false`. But the standard doesn't have anything to say about that as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FelixPalmen same reason why given `char a;` `sizeof(a) == 1` and `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` (in C). It's not about the implementation, it's about the language.

Comment: @n.m. `'a'` is a constant of type `int`, while `true` is a macro defined to the integer constant 1. I see a difference here, but it's certainly about how you interpret that wording.

Comment: @FelixPalmen What is this difference you are speaking of? I can't see any. After preprocessing, `1` is a constant of type `int`, just like `'a'`.

Comment: Have you tried to print `sizeof(true)`? perhaps it will make thins a bit more clear (in particular, it will become obvious that the ternary operator is a red herring).

Comment: @n.m. I'm referring to the ambiguity of the term "integer constant", that doesn't force the type to be `int`. Of course, if you read the `1` as the *literal* definition of `true` (I'm not sure it can be interpreted that way), *then* the type is `int`....

Comment: @FelixPalmen `true` is `#define`d to be 1 by `stdbool.h` so yes, this is the literal definition.

Comment: @FelixPalmen What ambiguity? Integer constants are defined in section 6.4.4.1 (whose name is "Integer constants"), and their types is specified in §5 of this section. It's indeed at least (`unsigned`) `int`.

Comment: @Virgile well, as a "lexical element", yes. I agree that's probably meant, and it doesn't even matter much because a `#define true ((_Bool)1)` wouldn't buy you anything, given implicit conversions and integer promotion. Still, even the chapter on "integer constants" has a contradiction in the "semantics" part...

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? a : a));` will also print out `4`, making this question a bit more interesting.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12887700/541686)...

Comment: This is a perfectly good question and should not be vote-to-closed as too broad (there are currently 2 such votes)

Comment: in **stdbool.h** true is 1 also an integer.... :)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

It's because you have `#include <stdbool.h>`. That header [defines macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) `true` and `false` to be `1` and `0`, so your statement looks like this:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? 1 : 0)); // Why 4?
```

`sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform.

Comment: "It's because you have #include <stdbool.h>"  No, it is not. `sizeof(a ? (uint8_t)1 : (uint8_t)0);` would also give a result of 4. The integer promotion of the `?:` operands is the important part here, not the size of `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Lundin: Both are important. As-written, the type is already `int` with no promotion. The reason you can't "fix" it is the default promotions.

Comment: @PeterSchneider This is not C++. This is C. In C++, `true` and `false` are *not* macros; they are keywords. They aren't defined to be `1` and `0`, but to be the true and false values of the `bool` type.

Comment: @PeterSchneider No, you learned something about C today. Don't confuse the two languages. In C++, `sizeof(true)` is 1. [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/UG6tEq).

Comment: True, mixed it up. Hadn't read carefully and was missleaded by cppreference-link. My fault, thank you. But I have this feeling about c++ anyway.

Answer (score 68):

> *Here, ternary operator return `boolean` type,*

OK, there's more to that!

In C, the result of ***this*** ternary operation is of type `int`. <sup>[notes below (1,2)]</sup>

Hence the result is the same as the expression `sizeof(int)`, on your platform.

---

Note 1: Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.18, `Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>`

> [....] The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. They
>   are
>
> `true`
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> `false`
>
> which expands to the integer constant 0, [....]

Note 2: For conditional operator, chapter §6.5.15, (*emphasis mine*)

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; **the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated),** [...]

and

> **If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be
>   determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands,
>   is the type of the result.** [....]

hence, the result will be of type integer and because of the value range, the constants are precisely of type `int`.

That said, a generic advice, `int main()` should better be `int main (void)` to be truly standard-conforming.

Comment: @user694733 umm..why not? `<stdbool.h>` defines the MACROS to be of type `int`..is that wrong?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK, I see that now, this seems indeed wrong, updated now.

Answer (score 60):

The ternary operator is a red herring.

```
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(true));
```

prints 4 (or whatever `sizeof(int)` is on your platform).

The following assumes that `bool` is a synonym for `char` or a similar type of size 1, and `int` is larger than `char`.

The reason why `sizeof(true) != sizeof(bool)` and `sizeof(true) == sizeof(int)` is  simply because `true` is **not** an expression of type `bool`. It's an expression of type `int`. It is `#define`d as `1` in `stdbool.h`.

<s>There are no rvalues of type `bool` in C at all. Every such rvalue is immediately promoted to `int`, even when used as an argument to `sizeof`.</s> Edit: this paragraph is not true, arguments to `sizeof` don't get promoted to `int`. This doesn't affect any of the conclusions though.

Comment: Nice answer. After I read the currently most upvoted answer, I was thinking all statements should evaluate to 4. This cleared things up. +1

Comment: Isn't `(bool)1` an rvalue of type `bool`?

Comment: `printf("%u\n", sizeof((char) 1));` prints `1` on my platform whereas `printf("%u\n", sizeof(1));` prints `4`. Doesn't this mean that your statement "Every such rvalue is immediately promoted to int, even when used as an argument to sizeof" is false?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The size and type of `true` etc doesn't really matter in the case of `?:` since it gets integer promoted to `int` anyhow. That is, the answer should address _why_ `?:` is a red herring.

Comment: @Lundin once you know that `sizeof(true)==sizeof(int)`, would you still wonder why `sizeof(1?true:false) == sizeof(int)`? Does it require a separate explanation?

Comment: Well... for example, go compile `sizeof(1?true:false) ` in C++ where the size of true and false is 1. Still the result 4.

Comment: @Lundin the questiin is specifically about C, not about any language with a name that begins with a C.

Comment: So compile `sizeof(1?(char)true:(char)false)` in C then. Same issue.

Comment: @Lundin The question doesn't ask about `sizeof(1?(char)true:(char)false)`. It asks about `sizeof(a ? true : false)`. That's what I'm answering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157869/discussion-between-n-m-and-lundin).

Comment: I think the answer addresses the issue in the best way possible. You are welcome to downvote or improve it.

Comment: `sizeof()` usually does not evaluate it's arguments, so that means that it does not promote them. It literally takes the size in bytes of the expression in the `( )`. There is an exception though when `sizeof()` does evaluates it's arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336577/5500589

Answer (score 33):

**Regarding the boolean type in C**

A boolean type was introduced fairly late in the C language, in the year 1999. Before then, C did not have a boolean type but instead used `int` for all boolean expressions. Therefore all logical operators such as `> == !` etc return an `int` of value `1` or `0`.

It was custom for applications to use home-made types such as `typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } BOOL;`, which also boils down to `int`-sized types.

C++ had a much better, and explicit boolean type, `bool`, which was no larger than 1 byte. While the boolean types or expressions in C would end up as 4 bytes in the worst case. Some manner of compatibility with C++ was introduced in C with the C99 standard. C then got a boolean type `_Bool` and also the header `stdbool.h`.

`stdbool.h` provides some compatibility with C++. This header defines the macro `bool` (same spelling as C++ keyword) that expands to `_Bool`, a type which is a small integer type, likely 1 byte large. Similarly, the header provides two macros `true` and `false`, same spelling as C++ keywords, *but with backward compatibility to older C programs*. Therefore `true` and `false` expand to `1` and `0` in C and their type is `int`. These macros are not actually of the boolean type like the corresponding C++ keywords would be.

Similarly, for backward compatibility purposes, logical operators in C *still* return an `int` to this day, even though C nowadays got a boolean type. While in C++, logical operators return a `bool`. Thus an expression such as `sizeof(a == b)` will give the size of an `int` in C, but the size of a `bool` in C++.

**Regarding the conditional operator `?:`**

The conditional operator `?:` is a weird operator with a couple of quirks. It is a common mistake to believe that it is 100% equivalent to `if() { } else {}`. Not quite.

There is a sequence point between the evaluation of the 1st and the 2nd or 3rd operand. The `?:` operator is guaranteed to only evaluate either the 2nd or the 3rd operand, so it can't execute any side-effects of the operand that is not evaluated. Code like `true? func1() : func2()` will not execute `func2()`. So far, so good.

*However*, there is a special rule stating that the 2nd and 3rd operand must get implicitly type promoted and balanced against each other with the *usual arithmetic conversions*. ([Implicit type promotion rules in C explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)). This means that the 2nd or 3rd operand will *always* be at least as large as an `int`.

So it doesn't matter that `true` and `false` happen to be of type `int` in C because the expression would always give at least the size of an `int` no matter.

***Even if you would rewrite the expression to*** **`sizeof(a ? (bool)true : (bool)false)`** ***it would still return the size of an*** **`int`** ***!***

This is because of implicit type promotion through the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: C++ does not actually guarantee `sizeof(bool)==1`.

Comment: @aschepler No but the real world outside the C++ standard does however guarantee it. Name one compiler where it isn't 1.

Comment: Hi. I think this answer would be better _without_ its first part. The second part answers the question. The rest, while interesting, is just noise.

Comment: @YSC This was originally tagged C and C++ both, so a comparison between their different bool types and the history behind them was necessary. I doubt I would have written the first part if not for the C++ tag. However, one has to understand why sizeof(bool) is 1 but sizeof(false) is 4 in C.

Answer (score 23):

Quick answer:

- `sizeof(a ? true : false)` evaluates to `4` because `true` and `false` are defined in `<stdbool.h>` as `1` and `0` respectively, so the expression expands to `sizeof(a ? 1 : 0)` which is an integer expression with type `int`, that occupies 4 bytes on your platform.  For the same reason, `sizeof(true)` would also evaluate to `4` on your system.

Note however that:

- `sizeof(a ? a : a)` also evaluates to `4` because the ternary operator performs the integer promotions on its second and third operands if these are integer expressions.  The same of course happens for `sizeof(a ? true : false)` and `sizeof(a ? (bool)true : (bool)false)`, but casting the whole expression as `bool` behaves as expected: `sizeof((bool)(a ? true : false)) -> 1`.
- also note that comparison operators evaluate to boolean values `1` or `0`, but have `int` type: `sizeof(a == a) -> 4`.

The only operators that keep the boolean nature of `a` would be:

- the comma operator: both `sizeof(a, a)` and `sizeof(true, a)` evaluate to `1` at compile time.
- the assignment operators: both `sizeof(a = a)` and `sizeof(a = true)` have a value of `1`.
- the increment operators: `sizeof(a++) -> 1`

Finally, all of the above applies to C only: C++ has different semantics regarding the `bool` type, boolean values `true` and `false`, comparison operators and the ternary operator: all of these `sizeof()` expressions evaluate to `1` in C++.

Comment: Good answer that actually manages to point out that it doesn't really matter what type `true` and `false` are, because the `?:` operands would get integer promoted to `int` anyhow. Thus `sizeof(a ? (uint8_t)true : (uint8_t)false)` will also yield 4 as result.

Comment: This answer covers the main important point, value getting promoted to `int`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from  which is what included in the source

```
#ifndef __cplusplus

#define bool    _Bool
#define true    1
#define false   0

#else /* __cplusplus */
```

There macros `true` and `false` are declared as 1 and 0 respectively.

however in this case the type is the type of the literal constants. Both 0 and 1 are integer constants that fit in an int, so their type is int.

and the `sizeof(int)` in your case is 4.

Answer (score -3):

There is no boolean datatype in C, instead logical expressions evaluate to integer values `1` when true otherwise `0`.

Conditional expressions like `if`, `for`, `while`, or `c ? a : b` expect an integer, if the number is non-zero it's considered `true` except for some special cases, here's a recursive sum function in which the ternary-operator will evaluate `true` until `n` reach `0`.

```
int sum (int n) { return n ? n+sum(n-1) : n ;
```

It can also be used to `NULL` check a pointer, here's a recursive function that print the content of a Singly-Linked-List.

```
void print(sll * n){ printf("%d -> ",n->val); if(n->next)print(n->next); }
```