# Why does sizeof(a ? true : false, a) operator printed one byte?

Tags: c, boolean, sizeof, conditional-operator, comma-operator

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010910/why-does-sizeofa-true-false-give-an-output-of-four-bytes) question, `sizeof(true)` or `sizeof(false)` is `4` bytes because `true` and `false` are macros and defined in `#include <stdbool.h>` header file.

But, here interesting output of program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() 
{
    bool a = true;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false, a));
                             /* ^^ -> expresion2 */
    return 0;
}
```

**Output([Live demo](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ySG1WD)):**

```
1
```

**C11 6.5.15 Conditional operator(P4) :**

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). **The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0;** the result is the value of the second
>   or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type
>   described below.110)

Here, `a` is a `bool` type and assigned value `true`, then inside the `sizeof` operator, the `conditional` operator executed **expression2** because `a` is a `true`.

So, `comma` operator part(expression3) not evaluated according to the standard and expression2 is a macro. So, according to that question, the output of macro is `4` bytes but here, the output of program is 1 byte.

So here, Why  `sizeof(a ? true : false, a)` printed `1` byte only?

Comment: What compiler are you using? `gcc` or `g++` ?. Give exactly your compilation command

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch GCC compiler.

Comment: But what compilation command. It behaves differently with  `gcc` and with `g++`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the question is tag with c...

Comment: Try putting brackets around `false,a` --> `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : (false, a)));`, you will get the output of program - 4.

Comment: your printf returns the value of `a`, not your ternary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters consider the following simple demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( _Bool ) = %zu\n", sizeof( _Bool ) );
    printf( "sizeof( bool )  = %zu\n", sizeof( bool ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( _Bool ) = 1
sizeof( bool ) = 1
```

According to the C Standard (7.18 Boolean type and values )

> 2 The macro

```
bool
```

> expands to _Bool.

Now let's consider the expression used in the `sizeof` operator in this call

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false, a));
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> Syntax

```
1 conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

That is the conditional operator has higher precedence than the comma operator.

So this expression

```
a ? true : false, a
```

is an expression with the comma operator and can be equivalently rewritten like

```
( a ? true : false ) , ( a )
```

The result of the expression is the second operand of the comma operator that is it is the expression `( a )`.

As it was shown above this expression has the type `_Bool` because the variable a is declared like

```
bool a = true;
```

where the macro `bool` expands to `_Bool`. So `sizeof( _Bool )` is equal to 1.

If you will rewrite the conditional operator the following way as it is shown in this call

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( a ? true : a ) );
```

then the output will be equal to the value returned by `sizeof( int )` (usually equal to `4`) because the type `_Bool` has less rank than the type `int` (the type of the constant integer literal of the expanded macro `true`) and as result the expression `a` will be implicitfly converted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions.

Comment: Does the sizeof operator evaluate the expression inside the parentheses?

Comment: @surendranath No, the expression itself is not evaluated. For example, int a = 1; printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( ++a ) ); printf( "%d\n", a ); the output for a will be 1.

Comment: Then, how is the sizeof operator printing 1? Is it because of the sizeof _Bool/bool or anything else?

Comment: @surendranath Because the expression has the type _Bool that has the size 1 that was shown in the demonstrative program.

Comment: @surendranath The result of the comma operator is the second operand. So the sizeof operator determinates the type of the second operand. If there is used the conditional operator then the sizeof operator determinates the common type of the second and third operands.

Comment: @surendranath - the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate the expression  (and the `()` are part of the expression).  However, it does determine the type of the result of that expression, even though it doesn't actually evaluate it.  Once it knows the type of the result, it can determine the size of that type.

Answer (score 10):

`a ? true : false, a` is two expressions, separated by the comma operator. It discards the result of the ternary operator and evaluates simply to `a`.

Since `a` is a `bool`, which in `stdbool.h` is a macro for `_Bool`, you print the size of the `_Bool` data type. It's more than likely that `_Bool` is just one byte, since all it needs to hold is the values 1 and 0.

To contrast it with the linked question, there you printed `true` and `false`, which `stdbool.h` defines as preprocessor macros for 1 and 0. The two are `int` constants, and therefore their size is the size of the `int` data type.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `1` because of comma operator used in the expression:

```
(a ? true : false, a));
```

[Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

So, in expression `(a ? true : false, a));` because of the comma operator, the result of ternary operator is getting discarded and then it evaluates the second operand and return `a`. Since `a` is of type `bool` so, your program is giving output as `sizeof(bool)` which is `1`.

Try putting brackets around `false,a`, like this:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : (false, a)));
```

When you put the expression `false, a` in brackets `()`, expression `(false, a)` will get evaluated first and the comma operator returns `a` but the ternary operator will evaluate the expression and return `true`,  which is a macro expands to the integer constant 1, and the output of the program will be `sizeof(1)` i.e. `4`.

Answer (score 0):

first statement in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

> "In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result"

so essentially

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false, a));
```

evaluates to

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
```

a is of type bool and rest is what you get as output.

Comment: The quote (from the Wiki) is crippled, incomplete in a way that is does not make sense in the context of the question.