# Are there any examples of C code which leads to (significant) performance decrease / increase after being compiled as C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, performance

This question may be asked before.

Are there any examples of C code which leads to (significant) performance decrease / increase after being compiled as C++ code?

---

UPD1: It's interesting to know about performance increase as well. Hence, added "increase".

UPD2. May be useful: [Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12887700/1778275)

UPD3. The "UnspecB/UB/IB aspect" is interesting. However, more interesting is perhaps to limit C code to be a strictly conforming C program (C11, 4p5), which is at the same time an UnspecB/UB/IB-free well-formed C++ program that 1) contains no violations of the rules in Clause 5 through Clause 33 and Annex D (N4917, 4.1.1p2.1), and 2) has the same (abstract) semantics.

Comment: not that I am aware of

Comment: C++ is sometimes more restrictive and what is perfectly fine in C is undefined behaviour in C++. But I cannot think of anything that stays defined but just gets slower.

Comment: Things (should) work the other way around: *OP* coming with a piece of code, compiled in the 2 ways and with the significant (might also define that) runtime difference, asking about reasons and ways to "solve" it. What's the end goal?

Comment: `#if __cplusplus` / `… lots of code …` / `#endif`

Comment: Anything that relies on compiler support for `restrict` optimization might suffer, since that's not part of standard C++ and is implementation-dependent. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776283).

Comment: Must the code have the same functionality when compiled in each of the languages?

Comment: This probably doesn't really qualify as _the same_ program, but sorting an array of user defined type in C++ using `std::sort` is likely much faster than in C using `qsort`.

Comment: Compiling a C program as C++, generally leads to change of semantics. There are subtle differences in interpreting similar code, that lead change of behavior. This affects performance, as well as correctness, safety and precision. If OTH a well designed C program is revised to a well designed C++ one - with similar logic - the result is more readable, often shorter and expected to be faster, yet safer.

Comment: @Red.Wave _well designed_ programs  are not safer in one language or another.  If code was not safe, it was no well designed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in C safety doesn't make sense; you can follow best practices, but serious bugs are only discovered at runtime. In C++, lots of them are prevented by sticking to basics, if only programmers knew what they were.

Comment: @Red.Wave I can follow best practices and avoid serious bugs any more than C++ - perhaps our experiences differ.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I guess there's a lot to learn, before you become seriously involved with C++. A simple tip: in C raw pointer is the King, while in C++, the black goat. Using raw pointers is not recommended in C++; double pointers are big NONO. Well designed C++ code looks generally different.

Comment: @Red.Wave The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366111/are-there-any-examples-of-c-code-which-leads-to-significant-performance-decrea?noredirect=1#comment136399875_77366111) is about C and the disagreement within "well designed ... yet safer".  "before you become seriously involved with C++" --> been continuously using C++ since before C++ compilers existed (mid '80s).  (Code was converted to C and then compiled).  Concerning tips: they do not apply here as question is about code suitable for both languages.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my point is whatever C++ can compile is not essentially, what should be written; C programming follows a totally different mindset. There's a difference between reuse and revision; for the former, you don't compile as C++; for the later, you better rewrite the code.

Comment: @Red.Wave, Still does not well support "well designed C program is revised to a well designed C++ one ... is ... safer."  I suggest our experiences differ.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this code, which doesn't make a lot of sense, but is easy to imagine more complicated code that does make sense and does something similar.

```
union
{
    long a;
    short b[sizeof(long)/sizeof(short)];
} foo;

short* ptr;

extern void work();

void func()
{
   foo.a = 1;                   // 1
   *ptr = 42;                   // 2
   if (foo.a == 1) work();      // 3
}
```

Assume that the rest of the code is UB-free and has the same meaning in either language.

When compiled as C++, `func` is going to be marginally faster at least with some implementations. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMreo31Mr). As you can see, when compiled as C++ it has no conditional jumps, while when compiled as C it does have one.

The reason is that different things have undefined behaviour in the two languages.

In C++, if `ptr` points to `foo.b`, the program has UB, because it would be illegal to modify one member of a union and then inspect another member. So the compiler assumes that `ptr` does not point to `foo.b` and the value of `foo.a`does not change at line 2, thus it still has the same value it had at line 1, this there is no need to check it at line 3.

On the other hand, in C, if `ptr` points to `foo.b`, the behaviour is perfectly (implementation-)defined. `foo.a` can change at line 2, and the compiler has no idea whether it does indeed change or not. Thus there is a need to perform the check at line 3. In reality the value of foo.a won't change, because we know that the program is valid C++ as well as valid C, but the compiler cannot know that.

Comment: If we are saying that this whole program is UB free, then a hypothetical C implementation could spot that `ptr` never points to `foo.b`, and do the same optimisation. You are right that current ones don't

Comment: @Caleth A compiler cannot prove such things in general, even if it has all the information about the program (equivalent to the halting problem).

Comment: Re: "illegal to modify", "behaviour is perfectly (implementation-)defined". In case of time, can you point to the relevant paragraphs in C and C++ standards?

Comment: @pmor C++ [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-2) and [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-2); C [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95).

Comment: Your "here and here" point to the same link. Consider fixing.

Comment: @pmor I forgot where it is supposed to point :( Maybe later when I have some time.

Answer (score 4):

- Consider the impact of function overloads:

```
long double a = ...; 
long double b = ...; 
long double c = pow(a, b);
```

With C, the function is a `double` one.  With C++, the function is a `long double` one.  C expected to be faster.  (or not given the cost of type changes.)

```
float a = ...; 
float b = ...; 
float c = pow(a, b);
```

With C, the function is a `double` one.  With C++, the function is a `float` one.  C++ expected to be faster.

---

- `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` in C. `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)` in C++.   Certainly potential to drive performance differences if the size affects loops, etc.

---

Comment: Re: pow. Would calling functions of different types (float, double, long double) technically lead to different program's semantics?

Comment: @pmor Perhaps.  I have often seen quick & dirty C code that uses `<math.h>` `double` functions where `float` or `long double` would make more sense.  Hard to make certain what is the author's true intent.

Comment: Any ideas whether using `_Float16` (if supported) would (generally) lead to better performance than (32-bit) `float`?

Comment: C is designed that for _integers_, there is a [Goldilocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle) type that is "just right" for _typical_ calculations and that is ostensibly `int/unsigned`.  The same somewhat holds true for _floating point_ types with `double`. As modern hardware/libraries can often perform `float` faster than `double`, and sub-`float` faster than `float`, the hope is that `_Float16` would lead to better performance, yet that is **implementation dependent**. `_Float16` certainly takes up less space.  I would not rely on sub-float as faster, just certainly smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real world example, but here is a program that is pretty much exactly 4 times as fast when compiled as C.

```
int s = 0;

int main(void) {    
    struct s { char c; };
    volatile int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 20) / sizeof(s); ++i) {
        n = i;
    }
}
```

[Idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887719/21285803)

Comment: Is the `Source` link correct?

Comment: Maybe use `sizeof 'a'` (`sizeof (int)` in C; `sizeof (char)` in C++) rather than invoke UB --- [C11 6.7.2.1p8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8) "If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any named members [...] the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @pmg: It needs to be `sizeof (s)` to exploit the fact that `struct s` puts `s` as a type name in the same namespace as that of `int s` in C++ but not in C. The remedy is to change the definition of `struct s`, not to change the `sizeof`.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, it's a modification but it uses the same trick to have different behaviour between C and C++

Comment: This is an example of programs with different semantics in C and C++, not a performance difference of the same semantics

Comment: @Caleth true, but still it technically answers the question :) However I agree it's probably not what OP had in mind.

Comment: The *meaning* of this code is different between the two languages. It makes no sense to compare performance of two programs that do visibly different things.

Comment: @Caleth Re: semantics. As I remember, in C abstract semantics and concrete semantics need not be equal ("An actual implementation need not evaluate..."). However, a conforming C implementation has requirements on observable behavior. I don't know how "things are going" in C++ w.r.t. this aspect. Do you?

Comment: @pmor the observable behaviour of the sample code is some number of writes to a `volatile` int, where C and C++ differ on the number, because they have different rules for what `sizeof(s)` evaluates to. Technically whether this has defined behaviour is implementation-defined, because `int i` might not be able to hold `(1 << 20) / sizeof(s)`, it's only *required* to be 16 bits

Comment: _"I agree it's probably not what OP had in mind"_  You should seek to improve the question by making comments or requesting clarification to make sure it aligns with the OP's intention *before* answering it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, by definition. When compiling C as C++ there are only 3 options:

1. Valid C is invalid C++, so you don't get any runnable code, so there's nothing to compare
2. Valid C is either UB or means something else in C++, so you get a runnable code that does something different (usually not what you wanted), so the two can't be compared
3. The rest (most) falls into "C++ is a superset of a subset of C" so as long as you stay within this subset, you get the same code by definition

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI How's your example not my #2: "Valid C is UB C++"? It's not same code, it's different code as the check is skipped.

Comment: In my example there is no UB in either C or C++, and the meaning of the code is exactly the same.