# What is the main reason not to compile c code with g++?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I used c in a project, and after some study, I found a better method with some c++ libraries, but I really don't want to rewrite the code (say, `printf` to `cout`).

I did some search, and I got: "They are two very different languages",  "DON'T DO IT", etc, but I never found a detailed explanation.

Why? Are there some recommended articles to read?

Comment: To me this questions sounds like "what is the main reason not to compile C# with javac?"

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but I just really don't get it. when I use g++ to compile some c code,  it still works and execute normally,   why?

Comment: The tools available in C and C++ to solve programming problems are vastly different. If you are not required to use C, it will be better to use C++ for long term benefit.

Comment: The fact that you are able to compile C code via g++ is tied to the fact that C and C++ share a common basis (therefore any C code using only the common basis is also valid C++ code)

Comment: so,  if I do pay attention to the c++ rules( say, type casting when using malloc),  and not to use the feature that c++ don't support,  it's actually OK to do that?

Comment: Rather look for an explanation, look at the differences in ideologies. [Start with RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). Look at the family of problems it solves. Then start looking further abroad.

Comment: If the C++ libraries are better, then use C++. I don't like the C++ libraries myself. They're much harder to version because of the tight binding against certain version of classes.

Comment: user4581301, that is interesting, thanks for the information : )

Comment: Maybe you'll find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile

Comment: 4386427  thanks!!!  I love this one!!!

Comment: `int new = 42;`, that's why :-)

Comment: `printf` is also part of the standard `C++` libraries to make it easy to compile `C` programs using `C++`. There is no problem in keeping it.

Comment: From the rules: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: sorry for that,  I will pay attention to the rule next time.

Comment: See [Incompatibilities Between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To your generic question, there's no *simple* answer. C++ only supports a *subset* of C. If you want to write code that's valid and *has the same sematics* in both languages, you're very limited. Some examples of C code that's not valid C++ are:

- Code that uses **keywords** of C++ that don't have a special meaning in C like `class`, `this`, `new` etc. To avoid confusion, you normally try to avoid these keywords in C, but it's of course not necessary.
- C has designated struct and array initializers and they are often a good idea in a typical C project. You could write for example

  ```
  struct foo {int a; char b; short c; };
  struct foo x = { .b = 'x', .c = 42 };
  ```

  this isn't valid C++.
- In C, you must write `struct foo`  to refer to a structure with *tag* foo, while C++ allows to just write `foo`. This has a strange consequence when it comes to `typedef`s. In C, you could have

  ```
  struct foo;
  typedef struct bar foo;
  ```

  This is just an example, the code is confusing of course. But it's **invalid** code in C++, because it would be unclear what you refer to when just writing `foo`. Therefore, in C++, a `typedef` with the same name as a `struct` tag **must** refer to the exact same type.
- C supports *flexible array members* as the last element of a `struct` like this:

  ```
  struct foo { int x; int a[]; }
  ```

  The size of `a` is determined when you allocate memory for that struct (adding `n * sizeof(int)`). This feature doesn't exist in C++
- In C, pointer casts are *almost* always wrong, while they can be used in C++ for casting between a base class and a derived one. Therefore, C has the concept of a *generic pointer* `void *` that can be converted without a cast. In C++, converting to and from `void *` **requires** a cast like with any other pointer type.

These are just the examples that I could think of immediately, there are probably more. So yes, it's never a good idea to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

---

> I used c in a project, and after some study, I found better method with some c++ libraries, but I really don't want to rewrite the code

For this problem, there's another simple solution. Divide your code into multiple **translation units**. There's no problem at all with a mixed C/C++ project, as long as the C and C++ source files are distinct.

So that means you factor out all the code using your C++ library in a C++ file and compile only that file with a C++ compiler. For the public interface of that C++ module, use `extern "C"` declarations and guard them with an `#ifdef __cplusplus` to hide them from the C compiler.

The structure could look like this (very simplified), if the part using C++ is in a translation unit called `module` here:

**module.h:**

```
#ifndef MODULE_H
#define MODULE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
// the C++ compiler will see this causing all declarations in the block to have C linkage,
// the C compiler won't see it (skipped by the preprocessor)
extern "C" {
#endif

int module_foo(int arg);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**module.cpp:**

```
#include "module.h"
#include <mycpplib> // example

int module_foo(int arg)
{
    // some C++ code using your C++ library
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "module.h"

int main(void)
{
     int x = module_foo(42);
}
```

You could build a complete program like this:

```sh
gcc -c -omain.o main.c
g++ -c -omodule.o module.cpp

# link them together, using the C++ library libmycpplib:
g++ -oprogram main.o module.o -lmycpplib
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm afraid of OP needs; I understood that he wanted to call C++ code from actual C code, which is not exactly the same problem.

Comment: The last paragraph should make clear how to desing this. An example would be quite large though ... maybe I'll add one later, have to go now.

Comment: Not really, because calling C++ from C code needs more than using `extern "C"`, some wrapping should be built.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès well, I added a minimal example (unfortunately still quite big), maybe it helps to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Splitting into multiple translation units is the way to go, +1.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Perfect!

Answer (score 6):

> I used c in a project, and after some study, I found better method with some c++ libraries, but I really don't want to rewrite the code( say, printf to cout).

There is no need to replace `printf()` with `cout`.  But at the same time it is not quite so simple as "Compile C code with a C++ compiler."

You'll need to run all your tests, QA, and verification steps, just as if you were porting to a new operating system.  This is because C++ is not actually 100% backward compatible with C code.  There are a few ways that C code may have been written which will break if compiled with a C++ compiler.

If you're lucky, a C++ compiler with all warnings enabled will highlight any problematic portions of your C code.  If you're less lucky, a small fraction of your C code may need to be updated to compile with a C++ compiler and run properly.

Try it.  Test it.  But don't bother trying to remove `printf()`, which is a perfectly nice function and still supported in C++.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is *not* a strict superset of C.  That is, legal C code is not necessarily legal C++ code.  Many of the typical differences are not syntactically valid in C++ and will fail to compile.  For example:

- Implicit `void*` to `T*` casts.
- Using identifiers that happen to be C++ keywords.
- Most features added to C in C99 or later.

A C++ compiler will generate errors about those, so those aren't too hard to find and fix if you have some patience.

Some differences could be valid in both languages but behave differently, however.  Such cases are harder to detect.  Some examples are shown at:

- [Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile) (as pointed out by 4386427's comment)
- [Write a program that will print “C” if compiled as an (ANSI) C program, and “C++” if compiled as a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c)

Answer (score 3):

GCC stands for *GNU Compiler Collection*, is an integrated distribution of compilers for several major programming languages. These languages are C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, Fortran, and Ada, etc. This means internally its:

- gcc: cc1 for C
- g++: cc1plus for C++

You can try this with `-x` option and detail are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x). Say, you want to compile your `*.c` files or `*.cpp` files use respective commands: `gcc -xc -lstdc -shared-libgcc (or -static-libgcc)` or `gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc (-static-libgcc)` respectively.

**The differences are:**

`gcc` will compile `*.c/*.cpp` files as C and C++ respectively, whereas `g++` will compile `*.c/*.cpp` files but they will all be treated as C++ files. Linking will also happen similarly i.e. g++ to link the object files it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (gcc does not do this).  g++ also has additional macros.

So you can compile C code with g++ and in fact mix both C and C++ code. Finally, the executable size may also changes based on the compiler.

Answer (score -4):

c++ language is backward compatible to all the c code , as it is the successor of c language . That is the main reason why your c code still compiles with g++. But for good programming practice write your code in c++ if u are compiling on g++ because PROBLEMS DO EXISTS.

Comment: This is condractitory. *"PROBLEMS DO EXISTS"* vs *"backward compatible to all the c code"* (the former is not true anyway, C++ lacks VLAs and designated initializers).