# Error in macro expansion

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have been trying to understand macro expansion and found out that the second printf gives out an error. I am expecting the second print statement to generate the same output as the first one. I know there are functions to do string concatenation. I am finding it difficult to understand why first print statement works and the second doesn't.

```
#define CAT(str1, str2) str1 str2

void main()
{
    char *string_1 = "s1", *string_2 = "s2";
    printf(CAT("s1", "s2"));
    printf(CAT(string_1, string_2));
}
```

Comment: This problem is not related to macros in the slightest.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295634/c-string-concatenation-of-constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the preprocessing "by hand":

`CAT` is supposed to take 2 input variables, and print them one after the other, with a space between. So... if we preprocess your code, it becomes:

```
void main()
{
    char *string_1 = "s1", *string_2 = "s2";
    printf("s1" "s2");
    printf(string_1 string_2);
}
```

While `"s1" "s2"` is automatically concatenated to `"s1s2"` by the **compiler**, `string_1 string_2` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I thought it would be the same as the first statement as the value in  string_1 is "s1" and string_2 is "s2"

Comment: All the preprocessor does is manipulate the source code itself, once that's done, the code goes through normal compilation, and must be valid for that purpose. As I explained, `string_1 string_2` is invalid, and can't compile.

Comment: @Pete `string_1` is a variable to be precise , and `"s1"` is a string literal . Both are treated in different manner .

Comment: @Pete `string_1` doen's have the value "s1". It's a pointer that points to a zero terminated string "s1".

Answer (score 8):

Concatenating string literals, like `"s1" "s2"`, is part of the language specification. Just placing two variables next to each other, like `string_1 string_2` is *not* part of the language.

If you want to concatenate two string variables, consider using [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) instead, but remember to allocate enough space for the destination string.