# Should I stop using the term C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I understand C and C++ are different languages but when I was learning C++ I was always told that **C is a subset of C++** or C++ is C with classes. And that was quiet true until the appearance of C++x0, C++11 (or the modern C++ 11/14/17 in general). In fact (specially when working on embedded systems) it's very likely to find code written in C++ but with a lot of parts written entirely in pure C language. Here I have several questions:

1. Should I stop using the term C/C++?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, how would I call a program that use a mix of C and C++?
3. Given that both of them are 'different' languages is it likely that at some point C++ compilers stop supporting code written in the C language (since modern c++ is diverging from the C mentality for basic stuff like pointers, dynamic memory handling, etc)
4. Is there right now any collaboration between the people who makes the standards of C/C++ to keep the compatibility
5. If #4 is yes, such collaboration could end up in the near future with the appearance of the *modern c++* (11/14/17)

I know that there already similar questions, but I'm sure that a lot of people share these doubts so I'm very interested to get good answers specially for the points that have to do with the C++ tendency in the near future.

Comment: *And that was quiet true until the appearance of C++x0, C++11* No, C89 is not a subset of C++98.

Comment: This has been [migrated to Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/298665/25936). I had to clear the actual migration history (which deleted the automated migration link) to deal with some technical nonsense (migrations getting locked upon rejection, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C was never a subset of C++. The most obvious example of this is `int new;`.  This has been true since C89 and C++98, and the languages have only grown further from each other as new standards have come out.

> Should I stop using the term C/C++

Yes

> If the answer to #1 is yes, how would I call a program that use a mix of C and C++?

A source file is written in one language or the other.  A program can consist of code from multiple languages working together, or an executable produced by linking different compiled objects.  You would say the program was written in C and C++, "C/C++" is not a language.

> Given that both of them are 'different' languages is it likely that at some point C++ compilers stop supporting code written in the C language

3) They never did. `int *a = malloc(10);`. [C](http://ideone.com/2G9xT1) and [C++](http://ideone.com/zWSPTF#view_cmperr_content) have long since diverged.  click the links or see below for a file that is fine with C89 and up, but isn't valid under any C++ standard.

4) afaik no, the working groups are aware of each other but the standards make the decisions that are best for themselves.

```
/* A bunch of code that compiles and runs under C89 but fails under any C++ */

/* type aliases and struct names occupy separate namespaces in C, not in C++ */
struct S { int i; };
typedef int S;


struct Outer { struct Inner { int i; } in; };
/* struct Inner will be Outer::Inner in C++ due to name scope */
struct Inner inner;


/* default return type of int in C, C++ functions need explicit return types */
g() {
    return 0;
}


/* C sees this as two declarations of the same integer,
 * C++ sees it as redefinition */
int n;
int n;


/* K&R style argument type declarations */
void h(i) int i; { }


/* struct type declaration in return type */
struct S2{int a;} j(void) { struct S2 s = {1}; return s; }


/* struct type declaration in argument, stupid and useless, but valid */
/*void dumb(struct S3{int a;} s) { } */


/* enum/int assignment */
enum E{A, B};
enum E e = 1;


void k() {
    goto label; /* C allows jumping past an initialization */
    {
        int x = 0;
label:
        x = 1;
    }
}


/* () in declaration means unspecified number of arguments in C, the definition
 * can take any number of arguments,
 * but means the same as (void) in C++  (definition below main) */
void f();

int main(void) {
    f(1); /* doesn't match declaration in C++ */
    {
        /* new is a keyword in C++ */
        int new = 0;
    }

    /* no stdio.h include results in implicit definiton in C.  However,
     * as long as a matching function is found at link-time, it's fine.
     * C++ requires a declaration for all called functions */
    puts("C is not C++");
    {
        int *ip;
        void *vp = 0;
        ip = vp; /* cast required in C++, not in C */
    }
    return 0;
}

/* matches declaration in C, not in C++ */
void f(int i) { }
```

I always feel it's worth mentioning that C *is* a subset of Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

> I was always told that C is a subset of C++ or C++ is C with classes. And that was quiet true until the appearance of C++x0, C++11 (or the modern C++ 11/14/17 in general).

C has never been a subset of C++. For example C89 is not a subset of C++98.

A few examples:

- the C89 *identifier-list form* for function parameter declaration is not supported in C++
- C89 and C++98 have different types for the characters constants
- C89 and C++98 have different types for string literals
- logical operators yield different types in C89 and C++98 (`int` vs `bool`)

> 1. Should I stop using the term C/C++?

Yes.

> 2. If the answer to #1 is yes, how would I call a program that use a mix of C and C++?

A program is either C or C++ (if even some very basic program can compiled with either a C or a C++ compiler). What compiler are you using to compile it? It should answer your question. Harbison & Steele coined the term [*Clean C*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694776/what-is-clean-c-and-how-does-it-differ-from-standard-c) to designate a common subset of C and C++ but I think it was a bad idea.

**EDIT**: However I admit that technically you can link C and C++ objects files in a single program but OTH there are many languages that are allowed to be mixed in a single program for example Java and C++. I think using the term C/C++ program only adds to the confusion that it is written in a single language called C/C++.

> 3. Given that both of them are 'different' languages is it likely that at some point C++ compilers stop supporting code written in the C language (since modern c++ is diverging from the C mentality for basic stuff like pointers, dynamic memory handling, etc)

There are many features (example: variable length array, flexible array member, `_Generic`, ...) of C99 or C11 that are not supported by any C++ version.

Answer (score 2):

> In general the SO users ask the person who is asking the question to choose a language: C or C++. Why?

There are many subtle differences between C and C++. For example, in C++, a `const` variable at global scope has internal linkage unless declared `extern`, but in C it has external linkage unless declared `static`. By saying "C/C++", the OP is asserting knowledge that the answer to their question is the same in both C and C++, when it very well might not be. **This needlessly makes things harder for would-be answerers.**

- Sometimes we can spot that the code isn't valid in one language or the other (for example, implicit conversions from `void*` to pointer to object are not valid in C++). This is annoying. Why are you saying "C/C++" when you have a piece of code that's valid in C but not C++? Did you intend C, or is this just an error in code intended to be C++?
- Sometimes the answer will be different depending on the language (for example, variable-length arrays exist in C99 but not in C++). If we don't know what language you're talking about, either we have to guess, or write an answer for both when only one will actually be useful, because *you know which language you're actually using; you're just not telling us!*
- Sometimes the answer really is the same for both languages, but it's hard to be sure. For example, I think C and C++ have the same integer conversion rules, but in order to be really, really sure, I have to read both standards carefully. Again, this makes me do twice as much work as necessary when you probably only care about one of the languages.

Anyway, to answer your other questions:

1. Yes.
2. If you are linking together C and C++ code, it is acceptable to use both tags, but please specify which language each file is in.
3. There are breaking changes sometimes, but they're rare and typically limited in impact (otherwise they don't get approved). For example, `auto` in C++11.
4. I don't think they directly collaborate, but they pay attention to developments in the other language and try to avoid introducing changes that would make compatibility more difficult.

And if you really do want to know about both languages, that's fine, and you can say that in your question. When you say "C/C++", I'm really not sure what you mean, and it really looks like you're making an assumption about the two languages.