# To what extent is it permissible to combine C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, multiple-languages

I'm writing a chat server for class. I'd like to use C's network protocols, but I'm more comfortable programming in C++, particularly in terms of string manipulation.

As I understand it, you can combine the two in a single file and compile for C++ and it'll still accept the C code so long as the proper #include's are there.

What are the limitations on this? What should I look out for? Is there anything in particular from C that *will not* work in a .cpp file?

Comment: I'm doing my work in gedit with g++ in ubuntu, but I should think this would be a universal sort of question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples

Comment: C is *almost* a proper subset of C++, but there are some nuances. As far as I remember, some operator precedences / associativities have changed. But now I'm really just guessing.

Comment: C is mostly a subset of C++, meaning that a large percentage of C code will compile with a C++ compiler.  However, there are some minor (but important) differences.  These differences have been enumerated and elaborated elsewhere on stackoverflow

Comment: C has network protocols? When was that added to C's standard library? Or are you talking about a C networking library?

Comment: Networking library. Forgive me. Arpa/inet, sys/socket, netinet/in, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to #include and use standard headers including the networking headers in C++ without doing anything special.

There are some differences between C and C++, but its unlikely you'll run into any problems because of it.

One difference is enums. In C, an enum is just an int. In C++, an enum is an actual type. This code is valid C, but invalid C++.

```
enum sport {
    hockey,
    baseball,
    soccer,
    vollyball
};

enum sport s = 5;
```

Compiling this with g++ gives

> test.c:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘sport’

[Here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) is more information on mixing C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

Don't combine the two in the same file. Writing C that compiles as C++ leads C people to yell at you, and vice versa. Instead, make a little C library, and have your C++ link against it. The only thing you need to do then is to add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

At the beginning of the header file for the C lib, and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

At the end.

It's easy, and pretty, too: Create a `Makefile`, since you're using gnu make, this is really easy:

```
program: cstuff.o program.o
```

With that, running `make` will issue the following commands:

```
cc -c cstuff.c 
g++ -c program.cpp
cc cstuff.o program.o -o program
```

So a directory listing will have 4 files: `program.cpp` `cstuff.c` `cstuff.h` and `Makefile`.

- `cstuff.h` contains all your structure definitions, and function prototypes, along with that `extern "C"` stuff,
- `cstuff.c` is self-evident, and
- `program.cpp` begins with `#include "cstuff.h"` can call the functions listed in the header file, and has all the C++-ey goodness you love.

Comment: Whoa my God I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Aerovistae I added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Usually everything goes quite fine when mixing C and C++, after all the latter inherited from the first much of the syntax.

Probably the most notable difference is that you will have to explicitly cast dynamically allocated memory:

```
int *array = (int*) malloc(...)
```

This because in C `void*` can be assigned to any type of pointer, while this is not true in C++, while in C you wouldn't need to do it. But in C++ you could simply avoid malloc and use directly new and delete.

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++) in any case, many differences are summarized, but they mostly are just slight ones.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is basically just an updated version of C with OOP methodology added. So combining them isn't really a problem. Most compilers support both anyway so you can combine them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

All libraries with "C interface" are usable in C++ code. In the worst case, you have to add `extern "C" { ... }` to specify that the "extern linkage" for the enclosed symbols is a la C and not a la C++. In the best case, the header to use that library already takes into account the possibility to be used inside C++ code, so all you have to do is to include it, and then use the functions of that library as you would do in C.

I am rather sure that in your case ("net"/sockets functions) it is enough to include the headers and add the libraries between those to be linked. (**ADD**) Of course, where the prototype wants `char *` you can't pass string, you have to use c_str() if you keep your string as C++ string object...