# If I want to write a C program, does it really matter if I choose a C or C++ file in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I am just learning programming really, and, while reading C++ Primer Plus (5th Ed.), I came across the statement that "any valid C program is a valid C++ program" and I am curious to see how far I can take that statement.

The book is pretty good, but is that statement *necessarily* true?

Is there any reason to **not** create a new file in CodeBlocks and choose that it be a C++ file despite my intentions of writing only C code for a particular project, instead of choosing to call it a C file? For example, maybe I will start writing something in C and realize down the road that I want to start using some of the C++ features, would it not have mattered what I decided in the beginning since I can just change the file extension afterwards?

Comment: Just because you _can_ write C++ which is also valid C does not mean you _should._ Pick one for a given program and stick with it.

Comment: That statement seems obviously false to me. `int main(void) { int class = 3; printf("%d\n", class++); }`. That's a valid C program (with the #include) but not a valid C++ program.

Comment: Why isn't it valid C++?  No return value?

Comment: It's not valid C++ because `class` is a reserved name in C++. You cannot name a variable `class` in C++, but you can in C.

Comment: Here's an easy candidate for C, but not C++: `int main(void) {int i = 1; int arr[i]; return 0;}`

Comment: While all these examples are correct, there are couple of important notes. First, most (if not all) **logical** incompatibilities are related to C99 compared to C++. There are still mainstream compilers not supporting C99 (hint: VC), so we can't always talk about C99 exclusively. Second, when using C++ compiler on C program (especially in C90), 99% of the errors will relate to problematic type enforcement which should better be fixed (and it will compile with C compiler as well).

Comment: @icepack: No, the main incompatibility that affects **all** properly written C software is that C++ lacks implicit conversions from `void *` to other pointer types. This breaks all correct usages of `malloc`.

Comment: I do not consider this logical incompatibility. That's stronger typing and C program will only benefit from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is outright false. There are plenty of C programs that are not valid C++ programs, and I would go so far as to say that **any** non-trivial C program that's properly written is not a valid C++ program. Hint: `char *p = malloc(n);` is not valid C++.

Answer (score 4):

C and C++ are two very different languages.  Yes, C++, for the most part, cooperates well with standard C syntax.  But C++ is object oriented and C is not.  Organization is very different between the two.

Learn C first. Learning C++ is a lot easier after learning C, and it is usually implied that you know at least basic C syntax before tacking an idea with C++.

Comment: "*But C++ is object oriented and C is not.*" C++ is also generic and C is not. C++ is also functional (to an extent) and C is not. I'm not sure why people get so hung up on OO...

Comment: You are correct, and I am learning C first and I have started with K&R, but I think you are missing my question entirely. I am just curious if it matters to the "computer/compiler" not to advocates of either language. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Ah, then maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples

Answer (score 0):

mostly no, but I think some libraries you may not be able to access if you choose C.

Answer (score 0):

I remember some C++ sentences cannot be compiled if your file is C language file(*.c), but it is usually OK, vice versa. Maybe due to that C++ is a superset of C.

And I think it is OK that whether your create a *.c or a *.cc/*.cpp file. The important thing when writing a C program and a C++ program, in my view, is the thinking style. C is a process language and C++ is an OO language.