# Visual Studio 2015: Extern "C" and the "export" keyword

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm working on migrating a large project from VS2012 to VS2015 (baby steps, I know), and I'm running into an issue with C headers no longer compiling, erroring out on reserved c++ keywords - even though they're being included with extern C.

Here's a simplified example (Compiles in 2012, but not 2015)

#### main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    #include "cheader.h"
}

int main()
{
    printfFromC();
    return 0;
}
```

#### cheader.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

extern int export;
int printfFromC();

#endif
```

#### ctest.c

```
#include "cheader.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int export = 0;

int printfFromC()
{
    export++;
    return printf("Hello from C (invocation %d) !\n", export);
}
```

with the following errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  main.cpp
c:\[...]\cheader.h(4): warning C4091: 'extern ': ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared
c:\[...]\cheader.h(4): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'export'
c:\[...]\cheader.h(4): error C3378: a declaration can be exported only from a module interface unit
```

#### Edit:

I made a mistake in creating the example - the keyword that's the cause of the trouble is `export` - not any c++ reserved keyword as I first thought. The example below has been modified to use `int export` instead of `int new`

Comment: @NathanOliver I made a mistake in creating the example - the keyword that's the cause of the trouble is `export` - not any c++ reserved keyword as I first thought.

Comment: `export` is also a reserved word in C++

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes - but the difference is this example compiles in 2012 now.

Comment: Because your ancient compiler did not support the C++11 Standard properly.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867325/how-to-link-old-c-code-with-reserved-keywords-in-it-with-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6):

The use of `extern "C"` controls name-mangling of the code it is applied to - it doesn't magically make the compiler compile that code as C. So when you `#include` the header containing `extern int export;` in `main.cpp`, it is compiled as C++ code, and as `export` is a reserved word in C++, you get a syntax error.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it compiles in VS2012 though - the app I'm migrating references a C library header that has these keywords.

Comment: It compiles because VS2012 did not support the C++11 Standard correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`new` is a keyword in C++. You can't use it as an identifier in cross-compiled code. This is the reason for the error. You'll have to come up with a different name for the variable.

Note that placing a portion of a C++ translation unit into `extern "C" { ... }` region does not mean that the code will somehow be compiled as C code. It simply means that external entities in that region will receive C linkage. The code itself is still compiled as C++ code and all C++-specific restrictions still apply.

Answer (score -1):

Digging further, the hack suggested here seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36869181/1486100

Changing main.cpp in the following way allows it to compile.

```
extern "C" {
    #include "cheader.h"
}

int main()
{
    printfFromC();
    return 0;
}
```

to

```
extern "C" {
    #define export extern_export
    #include "cheader.h"
    #undef export
}

int main()
{
    printfFromC();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, unsurprisingly changing the name `export` to something else will fix the problem. But only if the original name is never used anywhere, in which case why not remove it altogether?

Comment: No, it does not work, since it only affects the external declaration but does not affect the variable definition. Now your `extern_export` variable is undefined.

Comment: @AnT: Not sure what your point is - it's changing the name of the variable names defined by keyword, but doesn't actually affect anything that the c++ application would use, since it can't use those names anyway. This allows it to compile. Anything it's dynamically linked against will still work as expected.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is a simplified example - I'm trying to work around a vendor library we can't change.

Comment: @Tyzoid My point is that if you try using this variable in your C++ code under its new name, you will end up with linker errors, since the variable is not defined. Apparently, you don't care to use this variable on the C++ side and just want the header to compile - this is the important detail you forgot to mention.

Comment: @AnT I might be missing something, but I wouldn't think this to be an issue, given that the variable name before was a reserved keyword, so I would not expect to use it anywhere in my c++ program. You do raise a good point for future readers, though.

Comment: @Tyzoid But the point is that you _could_ have used it when your C++ code was compiled with VS2012 because the compiler would not recognise the keywords.  Anyway, you will find out when you try to link your code.