# Why should we use std name space before functions of <algorithm> header and should not use it before functions of <cmath> header?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, namespaces, std, cmath

I was wondering why we should use the `std` namespace before function of `<algorithm>` header like [max()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) and we are not obliged to use it before functions of `<cmath>` header like [round()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/)?

Examples:
[max()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE9nh.png)
[round()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MvDw.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cmath>` is essentially a wrapper around `math.c` from the C standard library.

> This header was originally in the C standard library as <math.h>.  (source:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath)

C++ is a (almost) a superset of C, meaning that a C++ compiler should compile almost any program written in C. For this reason functions from the C standard library do not belong to the `std` namespace, which is a C++'s concept. Other examples: `printf`, `fopen`.  Of course you can freely mix C++ standard library with C standard library functions, constants, macros etc.

For incompatibilities between C and C++ see for example [Where is C not a subset of C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/where-is-c-not-a-subset-of-c)